# How to set the font for a \section title (and chapter etc)

Tags: fonts, sectioning, titlesec, fontsize

How do I specify the fonts, and general font size, for the titles, chapters and sections in my document

**Update:**

I can see how my question is confusing.

I use `\section` and `\chapter` etc. to organise my document, and I would like to change the way the section and chapter titles are displayed.

Comment: The title of this post and the actual question are kind of confusing. Do you want to change the overall look of your document, or only one section?

Answer (score 80, accepted):

For the standard classes titlesec would be my choice. Here's an example using titlesec and the standard formatting/spacing, except that the font is changed to Helvetica (Arial has been derived from it) and the font color for demonstration. Adjust the \titleformat arguments to achieve what you desire.

```
\documentclass{report} 
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{mathptmx}% Times Roman font
\usepackage[scaled=.90]{helvet}% Helvetica, served as a model for arial
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\sffamily\huge\bfseries\color{blue}}
  {\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{20pt}{\Huge}
\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\sffamily\Large\bfseries\color{cyan}}
  {\thesection}{1em}{}
\begin{document}
\Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image]

With KOMA-Script classes it's easy as many other issues, just use `\setkomafont` and `\addtokomafont`. Here's the example:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt} 
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{mathptmx}% Times Roman font
\usepackage[scaled=.90]{helvet}% Helvetica, served as a model for arial
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\setkomafont{chapter}{\normalfont\huge\sffamily\bfseries\color{blue}}
\addtokomafont{section}{\color{cyan}}
\begin{document}
\Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to just adjust the color/font and keeping all the style information from the existing document class?

Comment: for KOMA, it might be better to `\setkomafont{disposition}{\foo}` since this works for all title commands... (It is overridden by fonts specified in the specific commands...)

Comment: Could you, please, tell me how to put the `chapter` and `chaptertitle` higher and to change the vertical gap between them and the text?

Comment: How do I apply that for all sections? In other words including subsections and subsubsections?

Comment: @CrazyQwert `\titleformat{\subsection}`etc.

Answer (score 24):

Depending on the level of customization you want, pick one of the following, in decreasing order of power/difficulty:

- read the Latex Companion and get your hands dirty programming
- [titlesec](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) package
- [sectsty](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/sectsty/) package
- [fncychap](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/fncychap) package
- [memoir](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/memoir) document class.

Comment: For the level of customization you're describing, sectsty seems to be the right balance of control and power. It gives you things like: `\allsectionsfont{\sffamily}` or `\chapterfont{\fontfamily{phv}\selectfont}` or such.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it's a bit more power than I need right now, but it might come in later