# Centering \section* and adding them to the ToC

Tags: sectioning, table-of-contents, horizontal-alignment, sections-paragraphs, starred-version

I'm using LaTeX and the `book` class and have one problem:

I want that my starred sections (only starred sections) appear in the center of the pages instead of the left side of the pages and also these sections to be added to the table of contents automatically.

Comment: I have not enough reputation yet, but I would recommend changing the title of this question and adding some tags such as `layout` and `toc`...

Comment: @Bran: Did that. Not adding `layout` though because half the questions here could be tagged that.

Comment: Maybe this question can give you some hints: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1455/how-to-set-the-font-for-a-section-title-and-chapter-etc

Comment: @Caramdir: True, `layout` does not make sense.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I recommend to create a new macro with a different name instead of changing the behaviour of `\section*` and thus redefining `\section`. A separate macro would be a cleaner solution.

The main LaTeX command for sectioning is `\@startsection`. It is documented in source2e.pdf, just type `texdoc source2e` at the command prompt. You would find it in *61.2 Sectioning*.

So, let's create a macro, use `\@startsection` with a `\centering` in the formatting argument:

```
\documentclass{book}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\@csection{\@startsection {section}{1}{\z@}%
  {-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
  {2.3ex \@plus.2ex}%
  {\normalfont\Large\bfseries\centering}}
\newcommand{\csection}[1]{%
  \@csection*{#1}%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#1}%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{First chapter}
\section{First section}
some text
\csection{A centered section}
more filler text.
\end{document}
```

Since `\@startsection` contains the `@` character, I had to use `\makeatletter` ... `\makeatother`. I defined an internal macro `\@csection` that does the sectioning. The final user command `\csection` calls this but additionally adds the entry to the table of contents.

`\csection` does what you asked for: it creates an unnumbered section-level heading with toc entry. Note, it doesn't support an optional argument, since this hadn't been a requirement.

If you need more customization, also regarding other sectioning commands, I recommend to use the [`titlesec`](http://ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) package. It offers a very good interface for sectioning customization.

Output:

[image: output]

Comment: Hi Stefan, thanks for your solution. It's exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 13):

You can define a new command to use in place of `\section*`, combining Bran's answer and the `\centering` command:

```
\newcommand{\secstar}[1]{\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#1}\section*{\centering #1}}
```

The new `\secstar` command takes the section name as an argument, then adds it to the the table of contents and creates a new `\section*`, centering the section title.  A complete example of its use is:

```
\documentclass{book}
\newcommand{\secstar}[1]{\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#1}\section*{\centering #1}}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{Test 1}
First numbered section
\secstar{Test 2}
An unnumbered section
\end{document}
```

Comment: Good! It works. It's less complicated than my example. I just hesitate to use `\centering` in a moving argument, but in this case of `\section*` that argument isn't used for toc or header entry, so it's causing no harm.

Comment: Hi Michael, thanks for your solution. The solution is short and really works fine.

Comment: Happy to help, Vahid.  Welcome to the site!

Answer (score 7):

For the second part of your question (adding these sections to the table of contents), you can use `\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{My chapter}` before specifying the `section` command.

Comment: Thanks, don't you have any idea for the first part of the question?

Answer (score 4):

It would appear that freshmen are neither allowed to comment, nor did a proposed edit of the above pass peer review.  So unfortunately I am forced adding a separate answer.

The above proposals of using `\addcontentsline` are faulty since `\section*` encourages page breaks before the section start, detaching the `addcontentsline` and leading to a page entry that is one page too early.

One way to fix that would be rewriting the proposed definition as

```
\newcommand{\secstar}[1]{\section*{\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#1}\centering #1}}
```

Of course, it would be easier to use the KomaScript classes and their `\addsec` command.  This would also affect the running page header otherwise left unchanged.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This is also an issue that one should keep in mind.