# Numbering subsections in one section only

Tags: sectioning, numbering

I have a document in which I generally do not want to number the chapters, sections and subsections. Only one section should contain roman numbered subsections, how do I achieve that? I tried

```
\documentclass{report}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-1}

\begin{document}

\chapter{mwe}
\section{unnumbered subsections}
\subsection{unnumbered}

\section{roman numbered subsections}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{2}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\textnormal{\roman{subsection}}.}

\subsection{roman one}
\subsection{roman two}
\end{document}
```

However, this gives me an error at the `\section{roman one}` stating: Missing number treating as zero. Any suggestions for correction or ideas on alternative approaches?

Comment: The example gives no error, only with `article` before the edit. However, you should change the base value of secnumdepth from 0 to -1, see my answer.

Comment: @user7091: There's no need to edit the titles of your questions to inclue `keyword |`: That's what the tags are for, they get shown directly underneath the question title on the main page.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you change the document class from `article` to `book` or `report`, your document works without error. The code in your question uses the `\chapter` command which is undefined in the `article` class. Try:

```
\documentclass{book}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-1}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{mwe}
\section{unnumbered subsections}
\subsection{unnumbered}
\section{roman numbered subsections}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{2}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\textnormal{\roman{subsection}}.}
\subsection{roman one}
\subsection{roman two}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-1}
\chapter{Second chapter}
\section{unnumbered subsections}
\subsection{unnumbered}
\end{document}
```

Sometimes it's good to use `\addtocounter` instead of `\setcounter`, so you could raise or lower the numbering level without using the absolute value.

Also, as you can see, I used the counter value -1 for not numbering chapters, instead of 0.

In general, I think it's a bit inconsistent to change the numbering depth within a document.

Comment: I identified the real problem and [posted it here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33233/problems-using-titlesec-package). Thanks for your efforts

Answer (score 6):

Instead of messing manually with the counters, try the *starred* versions of the sectioning commands, they exclude numbering (and the entry in the table of contents, for that matter):

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\section*{unnumbered subsections}
\subsection*{unnumbered}

\section*{roman numbered subsections}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\textnormal{\roman{subsection}}.}

\subsection{roman one}
\subsection{roman two}
\end{document}
```

Edit: If you want to include the starred sections in the ToC again, please read up the procedure in 
[Centering \section* and adding them to the ToC](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2030/centering-section-and-adding-them-to-the-toc/2035#2035).

Comment: His original code works now because he changed from `article` to `report`. `report` has support for chapters where `article` does not.

Comment: Yes it does. I wasn't aware that the problem lay elsewhere. If interested, [see here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33233/problems-using-titlesec-package).