# How to get non-numbered sections to show in ToC

Tags: sectioning, table-of-contents, numbering, starred-version

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Centering \section* and adding them to the ToC](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2030/centering-section-and-adding-them-to-the-toc)
>   [Adding unnumbered sections to TOC](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11668/adding-unnumbered-sections-to-toc)

I'm writing a `book` and I want the sections within the main text to carry no numeration, while I want the section number to appear in the ToC. To suppress internal numeration, I write `\section*{Title}`, but if I do that it doesn't show up in the ToC. Any way around this?