# How do I include a \section*{} in a \tableofcontents?

Tags: sectioning, table-of-contents, starred-version

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Centering \section* and adding them to the ToC](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2030/centering-section-and-adding-them-to-the-toc)

I've got something like

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section*{About this Article}
\section*{About this Author} 
\section{First Step}
\section{Second Step}
\end{document}
```

My table of contents won't show the "About this Article" and "About this Author" sections.

[image]

How do I retain the format of `\section*{...}` yet still show the section in the table of contents?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Centering `\section*` and adding them to the ToC](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2030/5764)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use `\addcontentsline` to add the `section*` to the TOC:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section*{About this Article}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{About this Article}

\section*{About this Author} 
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{About this Author}

\section{First Step}
\section{Second Step}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

The whole point of a `\section*` is not affecting running headers and table of contents.  In this case, this means that "About this Article" and "About this Author" will be be given running headers of "Table of Contents".  So the main question here appears to be "Do you know why you are using `\section*` instead of `\section`?".

The KomaScript classes offer `\addsec` commands for creating unnumbered but otherwise identical sectional commands.

Comment: I think you should remove the last sentence of the first paragraph.

Comment: Sure, because people vote me down.  But not being a registered user, I can't make use of those points anyway, and the original poster of this question (and readers of it) will eventually run into this problem.  Sure it earns points to give people what they ask for, but I don't see the point in encouraging them to shoot themselves in the foot because of some award system.

Comment: I don't know about the "unregistered" issue, but you could post a question on [Meta.TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/) to get that resolved. Also, I do not see any down votes on this question,   and was **not** suggesting you remove the answer, just that the last sentence as I don't see how that adds value to your answer.

Comment: I am unregistered by choice.  And rest assured, I *did* observe the drop in reputation and answer score.  And answers, in contrast to comments, can't be removed.  You can "edit" them leaving a single character in place, but that's all.  The best I could do is to flag it as inappropriate content (or you could) and have a moderator remove it.  Go ahead if you think it worth the trouble.

Comment: It seems that there has been a miscommunication. I was only suggesting removing the comment `So the main question here appears to be "Do you know what you are doing?"` I was **not** suggesting you delete the answer.  There is no problem in answering a question with recommending that they not do something.  BTW, there is NO down on this answer that I can see.  Not sure how much rep you need to see the up/down votes.

Comment: "The whole point of a \section* is not affecting running headers and table of contents." I disagree with your statement.

Comment: There is something very useful in this answer (for European TeXers at least): the KomaScript `\addsec` command, of which I was unaware, that perfectly answers the original question (as far as I understand it - contrary to the  last sentence of the first paragraph of this answer, I believe the question was quite valid).