# \tableofcontents does not list the unnumbered chapter

Tags: table-of-contents

My question is just like the title. Here is a MWE for my case :

```
\usepackage[paperwidth=16cm,paperheight=24cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsxtra,amssymb,latexsym,amscd,amsfonts,enumerate,ifthen,stmaryrd,amsthm,amstext}
\usepackage[mathscr]{eucal}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage{multicol,color}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{vietnam} 
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{perpage} 
\MakePerPage{footnote}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} 
\makeindex
\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\tableofcontents 
\chapter*{Foreword}
 Blah blah blah
 \chapter*{Preface}
 \pagenumbering{arabic}  
  Blah Blah
  Mirella gọi là papa, dạy toán ở nhà cho Mirella. 
 \thispagestyle{plain}
 \chapter{Dido's problem}
 \label{chapter:Dido}
 \index{Dido (công chúa)} \index{bài toán công chúa Dido}
   Blah blah blah
  \end{document}
```

Why the unnumered chapter does not appear in the table of content ? Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: This is very similar in flavour to: [How to remove chapter numbering without removing it from `\tableofcontents`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/110840/5764); [How do I include a `\section*{}` in a `\tableofcontents`?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/58863/5764) and [How to use `\section*{something}` without removing it from the Table of Contents?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/106480/5764)...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Starred sectional units don't produce entries in the ToC. You can add them using

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{<unit>}{<text>}
```

(and `\phantomsection` if hyperref is used). A complete example:

```
\documentclass{book}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents 
\chapter*{Foreword}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Foreword}
Blah blah blah
\chapter*{Preface}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Preface}
Blah Blah
Mirella gọi là papa, dạy toán ở nhà cho Mirella. 
\chapter{Dido's problem}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you are using the `book` document class, it's better to use `\frontmatter` and `\chapter` for the initial introductory units, and then `\mainmatter` for the main body of the document:

```
\documentclass{book}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\tableofcontents 
\chapter{Foreword}
Blah blah blah
\chapter{Preface}
Blah Blah
Mirella gọi là papa, dạy toán ở nhà cho Mirella. 
\mainmatter
\chapter{Dido's problem}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It works. Thank you very much @Gonzalo Medina !