# Inserting \chapter* title to TOC

Tags: table-of-contents, chapters, books

I'm writing a book using Latex

```
\documentclass[parskip=full,12pt,a4paper,twoside,frenchb,openany,fleqn]{book}
```

How can I add my \Chapter* to my TOC, because only \chapter titles appear.

Comment: take a look at [\tableofcontents does not list the unnumbered chapter](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/129689/579)

Comment: [Non numbered chapter\* header issue](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/199086)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
 \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{name}
```

to make an entry in your table of contents.

```
\documentclass[parskip=full,12pt,a4paper,twoside,frenchb,openany,fleqn]{book}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Test}
\section{Test}
\chapter*{Test2}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Test2}
\end{document}
```