# Chapter section doesn't appear in the table of contents with a book

Tags: sectioning, chapters

I'm using book style, but it happens with a report style, too. I'm using the `\chapter*` command and I want that the chapter section appears in the table of contents, but it doesn't appear. This is the code:

```
\documentclass[14pt,a4paper,twoside,spanish,openany]{book}
\usepackage[spanish,activeacute]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,amsthm, mathtools}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\renewcommand{\baselinestretch }{1.3}

\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Teorema}[section]
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lema}[section]
\newtheorem{proposition}{Proposición}[section]
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corolario}[section]

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definición}[section]
\theoremstyle{example}
\newtheorem{example}{Ejemplo}[section]
\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem{remark}{Nota}


\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{TEMA 3}
\rhead{\thepage }
\chead{Combinatoria}
\rfoot{Oposiciones}
\rhead{\thepage }
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt} 
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}

\begin{document}
\author{Cristobal López Silla}
\title{Tema 3 - Técnicas De Recuento.Combinatoria.}
\date{}
\tableofcontents

\pagebreak

\chapter*{TEMA 3.\\Técnicas De Recuento.Combinatoria.}
\section{Introducción A Las Técnicas De Recuento.}

\end{document}
```

Thanks

Comment: relevant: [\tableofcontents does not list the unnumbered chapter](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/129687/579)

Comment: Your answer can be found here: [Creating unnumbered chapters/sections (plus adding them to the ToC and/or header)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/35433/5764). Use `\chapter*{...} \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{...}`. But be careful not to insert stuff like ``\\``, since that wouldn't make sense.

Answer (score 2):

There is a bunch of ways of adding `\chapter*` like titles to the ToC. I changed the `\@makeschapterhead{}` command for automatic entries to the ToC.

The `\\` has to be protected, but in my opinion, it should not used at all in a chapter title.

```
\documentclass[14pt,a4paper,twoside,spanish,openany]{book}
\usepackage[spanish,activeacute]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,amsthm, mathtools}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\usepackage{xpatch}%

\renewcommand{\baselinestretch }{1.3}

\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Teorema}[section]
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lema}[section]
\newtheorem{proposition}{Proposición}[section]
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corolario}[section]

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definición}[section]
\theoremstyle{example}
\newtheorem{example}{Ejemplo}[section]
\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem{remark}{Nota}


\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{TEMA 3}
\rhead{\thepage }
\chead{Combinatoria}
\rfoot{Oposiciones}
\rhead{\thepage }
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt} 
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}

\begin{document}
\author{Cristobal López Silla}
\title{Tema 3 - Técnicas De Recuento.Combinatoria.}
\date{}
\tableofcontents
\clearpage
%\pagebreak

\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\@makeschapterhead}{%
  \Huge \bfseries  #1\par\nobreak%
}{%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect\numberline{}#1}%
  \Huge \bfseries  #1\par\nobreak%
}{}{}
\makeatother


\chapter*{{TEMA 3.\protect\\ Técnicas De Recuento.Combinatoria.}}
\section{Introducción A Las Técnicas De Recuento.}

\end{document}
```

[image]