# Number equation as 0.1 instead of 1

Tags: equations, numbering, align, books

I am using `book` class for my thesis. I have a preface which is before the first chapter. In this preface, all sections are numbered like `0.1` etc. However, equations are numbered as `1` instead of `0.1`, which looks strange. How can I ask LaTeX to number my equations in preface like `0.1`, `0.2`, etc, please? Thank you!

Comment: Sounds strange that you want sections numbered `0.1`, wouldn't unnumbered sections (`\section*{...}`)  be better for the preface?

Comment: Could you provide a minimal example with the preface, to make it easier to answer your question? In the mean time, you could take a look at, e.g., http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/61756/how-to-change-equation-numbering-style to get started.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. If I use `\section*{}`, i.e., no numbering of sections. What should I do with the equations, please? Should I leave it as `1` instead of `0.1`? What is the common practice?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. By the way, I also have theorems in the preface. And currently they are also numbered as `0.1` and alike. What should I do with them?

Comment: So far un-asked: Why do you have equations in the preface at all? And, do these equations need to be numbered?

Comment: @Mico Yes, because I will refer to them later.

Comment: `\counterwithout{equation}{section}` for the unnumbered section, needs `chngcntr` package

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Also after I use `\section*{}`, all the sections are no longer in TOC.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Could you give a bit more detail, please? Where to add your command?

Comment: @LaTeXfan: I was wrong -- do you have a section in your preface?

Comment: As far as i see it, the preface should have a few common introductory words. The real deal happens in your mainmatter.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Yes. In fact, several sections.

Comment: Perhaps a complete example would make it more clear. Though on hindsight I understand why Johannes and Mico question the use of equations and theorems in a preface, it doesn't really seem like the place for them. Anyways, I don't know what the common practice is, if there is one. Unnumbered sections can be added to the ToC, see e.g. [How do I include a \section\*{} in a \tableofcontents?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/58863)

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Agreed -- and I wouldn't use `0.1` numbering anyway...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long there is no clear setup: Perhaps this one?

```
\documentclass{book}


\usepackage{chngcntr}

\begin{document}

\counterwithin{equation}{chapter} % Use chapter as driver for the resetting

\section{A section}

\begin{equation}
  E = mc^2
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
  c^2 = a^2+b^2
\end{equation}


\chapter{Real stuff}



\section{A section}

\begin{equation}
  E = mc^2
\end{equation}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I am convinced of not using `0.1` and alike. Just look not so nice.

Comment: @LaTeXfan: If you want to have `0.1` -- it's there now. I wouldn't it for my personal usage, as well as `0.` sections

Comment: Yes. Thanks for that. As I wrote earlier, I agree it does not look good. But if I use `\section*{}`, is it good to number equations `1` and so on? Remember in later chapters, all equations will be numbered like `1.2` and `2.2` etc.

Comment: @LaTeXFan no problemo. You'd refer in the text to equation 1 or 5.17, noone gets confused. But a preface with equations important enough to warrant numbering (and referencing) sounds strange. Perhaps use unnumbered `equation*`?

Answer (score -1):

Place `\renewcommand\theequation{\arabic{equation}}` just before your equation.

Example:

```latex
\renewcommand\theequation{\arabic{equation}}
\begin{equation}
\label{eqn:eq1}
X = 1+5
\end{equation}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX-SX! As a new member, it is recommended to visit the [Welcome](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) and the [Tour](https://tex.stackexchange.com/tour) pages to be informed about our format.
However, your post is not really answering to the original question.