# How to add a section* to the list of contents, but without giving it a number?

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, abstract

I have several section* 's in my LaTex text. But I only want the first one (abstract) to appear in the list of contents, although without a number. All the other section* 's are just a few subheadlines which should not appear anywhere and also don't have a number so far, which is good. Is there any exception regulation for this case only?

Comment: `\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Abstract}`

Comment: Which documentclass? If you use KOMA you can use `\addsec`

Comment: Are you sure you want to use `\section*` and not something like `\paragraph`?

Answer (score 0):

KOMAscript solution:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\newcommand{\Section}[1]{%
  \section*{#1}
  \addxcontentsline{toc}{section}{#1}
}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\Section{Abstract}
\begin{abstract}
This is my abstract
\end{abstract}
\section{First section}
This is my text.
\end{document}
```

In older versions of KOMAscript and with other document classes you’d probably have to use `\addcontentsline` instead of `\addxcontentsline` (note the `x`), or load `\usepackage{tocbasic}`. As far as I know the only difference is whether the option `numberline` is supported for unnumbered TOC entries.

Other than that [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/2038/41085) has been given before.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try something like this:

```
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents{
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Abstract}
}


\section*{Abstract}

\section*{First Section}

\section*{Second Section}

\end{document}
```

Which has this output:

[image]

Comment: Yes, this works, but I want to have all the other section* 's I used so far not to do the same, like they should not be in the list of content. So it's just for this one exception!