# What is the simplest way to typeset an entire document in sans-serif?

Tags: fonts, sans-serif

How do I typeset an entire document in sans-serif, e.g. Helvetica, without littering the document with font changes for every heading/paragraph, etc.? Like in [How to set the font for a \section title (and chapter etc)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1455/how-to-set-the-font-for-a-section-title-and-chapter-etc/1477#1477), but with the paragraphs all in sans-serif.

For example, I've seen documents typeset in Computer Modern and then switched to Palatino, but can I do the same with Helvetica with a few commands at the beginning?

(And please don't tell me to use a serif font for body copy / paragraphs. I know. I'm trying to use latex to typeset my resume to look like the one I've created in a word processor, which is hard to maintain but looks good. I'm hoping latex will let me do more advanced formatting/layout, separating content from form.)

Answer (score 157, accepted):

`\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}` will switch to using sans-serif for everything except mathematics. The sans-serif will be computer modern sans unless you also put `\usepackage{helvet}` in the preamble in order to set the default sans font to a [clone of Helvetica](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nimbus_Sans#Nimbus_Sans_L) (or `\usepackage{avant}` for Avant-Garde, etc.).

Comment: Is the font embedded in the resulting PDF?

Comment: Usually yes, although it's possible that a particular distribution has been installed so that that isn't the default.  For most standardly installed distributions, though, font embedding is enabled by default, AFAIK.

Comment: @Lev, Is there a package that does this automatically?, that is, without the ugly `\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}` code. (Nothing against it, but this is the kind of code makes me embarrassed to explain to newcomers)

Comment: The command `\usepackage{helvet}` does not provide Helvetica font, but an Helvetica clone called [Nimbus Sans L](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nimbus_Sans_L#Nimbus_Sans_L).

Comment: @alfC: some packages (eg: [sourcesanspro](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/sourcesanspro/), [cabin](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/cabin/)) provide an option. The [LaTeX Font Catalogue](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/) will show this in the code example for most (but not all) packages.

Comment: @Silex, thanks. Most Latex Font Catalogue examples I can find are a combination of a `package` and some "ugly" command. For example http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/arial/ which reads `\usepackage[scaled]{uarial}
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`

Comment: I changed the font style of my document to Helvetica using the commands written above `\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}` and `\usepackage{helvet}` in the preamble. Now I decided I actually don't like how it looks like. I erased the commands and compiled the document again, but it's giving me the same Helvetica font style. How can I change to the default LaTeX-font again?

Comment: @Rober Did you clean up your working files (delete the temporary build files) before you compiled again after those changes?

Comment: @alfC Is `\usepackage{fixthefonts}` so much less ugly than `\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}`? For newcomers I think it's good to just show them the default `article` style with `lipsum` and then insert/remove commands and see how the document changes. There's no getting around the "programming" (non-WYSIWYG) nature of LaTeX, in my opinion. They will have to _want_ to edit a plain-text file of commands, or else they want LyX/something else.

Comment: @isomorphismes, yes it is! Where can I find the package `fixthefont`?             :)

Comment: @alfC haha. ok ;) I definitely sympathise with the idea that TeX/LaTeX is the opposite of newbie-friendly (user-friendly, even).

Comment: This doesn't work with KOMA Script.

Comment: @LevBishop How to change font-family for whole document including math mode?

Answer (score 7):

The best way to have BOTH the text AND the math is just by adding:

```
\usepackage{cmbright}
```

in the preambule of the LaTeX document. It gives a nice and homogenous look to your document.
Cheers!

Comment: cmbright is nice but in what sense it's the best solution?

Comment: I believe it is, if you want both the text and the math to be without serif, which was the initial question :)

Comment: it seems that this font is not vectorized correctly, zooming in shows that the font is very pixelated? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2095/what-is-the-simplest-way-to-typeset-an-entire-document-in-sans-serif

Comment: On my computer (another one from which I compiled the initial document I am checking cmbright on), I can zoom in 6400% with still no pixelation of the characters... To me, everything seems great so far. Have you tried another pdf viewer?

Answer (score 6):

In ConTeXt you obviously use `\setupbodyfont`.  This will not affect math mode.

```
\setupbodyfont[ss]

\starttext

Sans-Serif

\stoptext
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`fontsetup`](https://ctan.org/pkg/fontsetup) package for easy configuration of fonts if you are willing to use XeLaTeX/LuaLaTeX. It supports two sans serif fonts Fira Sans and GFS Neohellenic, both with math support as of writing this answer.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[fira]{fontsetup}
%\usepackage[gfsneohellenic]{fontsetup}

\begin{document}
    \section{Some section header.}
    The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
    THE QUICK BROWN FOX JUMPS OVER THE LAZY DOG.
    1234567890
    \begin{align*}
        \oint_{\gamma} \sum_{i=0}^n \int \bigcup \bigcap \\
        \symup{\alpha \beta \gamma \delta \epsilon \zeta \eta \theta \iota \kappa \lambda \mu \nu \xi \omega \pi \rho \sigma \phi \psi \tau \omega}\\
        \alpha \beta \gamma \delta \epsilon \zeta \eta \theta \iota \kappa \lambda \mu \nu \xi \omega \pi \rho \sigma \phi \psi \tau \omega \\
        \partial \hbar \symbb{R, C, N, Z, Q}
    \end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Fira: [image: fira]
GFS Neohellenic: [image: gfsneohellenic]

There exists [Lato Math](https://github.com/abccsss/LatoMath), but not on CTAN, probably because it is not polished enough. Generated `.otf` file from GitHub: [LatoMath.otf](https://github.com/abccsss/LatoMath/releases/download/v0.1/LatoMath.otf).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{Lato}
\setmathfont{LatoMath.otf}

\begin{document}
    \section{Some section header.}
    The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
    THE QUICK BROWN FOX JUMPS OVER THE LAZY DOG.
    1234567890
    \begin{align*}
        \oint_{\gamma} \sum_{i=0}^n \int \bigcup \bigcap \\
        \symup{\alpha \beta \gamma \delta \epsilon \zeta \eta \theta \iota \kappa \lambda \mu \nu \xi \omega \pi \rho \sigma \phi \psi \tau \omega}\\
        \alpha \beta \gamma \delta \epsilon \zeta \eta \theta \iota \kappa \lambda \mu \nu \xi \omega \pi \rho \sigma \phi \psi \tau \omega \\
        \partial \hbar \symbb{R, C, N, Z, Q}
    \end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image: lato]

You can use the [`notomath`](https://ctan.org/pkg/notomath) package for sans serif text and math (on pdfLaTeX, LuaLaTeX and XeLaTeX). Noto math has open type support planned for the future as well.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[sfdefault]{notomath}

\begin{document}
    \section{Some section header.}
    The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
    THE QUICK BROWN FOX JUMPS OVER THE LAZY DOG.
    1234567890
    \begin{align*}
        \oint_{\gamma} \sum_{i=0}^n \int \bigcup \bigcap \\
        \alpha \beta \gamma \delta \epsilon \zeta \eta \theta \iota \kappa \lambda \mu \nu \xi \omega \pi \rho \sigma \phi \psi \tau \omega \\
        \partial \hbar \mathbb{R, C, N, Z, Q}
    \end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image: notosans]

I don't know how to make the summation and the integral signs sans serif in Noto.

Answer (score 1):

In OpTeX, you can declare (for example):

```
\fontfam[heros]
```

Then the complete document is in sans serif (including Unicode-Math).

Comment: Thanks for calling me a hero, you’re too kind.

Answer (score 1):

**Update:** I now slightly prefer `sansmathfonts` over `newtxsf`. `sansmathfonts` seems to be missing some higher-level symbols like `\leftrightarrow`, but I noticed that `newtxsf` also replaces the font for numbers, making numbers in math mode look different from numbers in text, which I very much disliked and couldn't find a more specific fix for. What I use now is

```
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}
\usepackage{sansmathfonts}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
```

---

**Original answer:** No existing solution I found on SE or elsewhere worked for me, with the most common problem being pixelated math fonts. After testing many random packages and commands, I finally pieced together something that seems to work alright.

```
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}
\usepackage{newtxsf}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
```

This preamble gives me *non-pixelated*, sans-serif text and math. Note that the order can make a difference, for example it seems to be essential to load

```
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}
```

before

```
\usepackage{newtxsf}
```