# How do I change a font document wide?

Tags: fonts, sans-serif

How do I change a font for a latex document?

I am using the `\documentclass{article}`, which sets the document in a serif font. 
I also declared `\usepackage{helvet}`, since that's the font I would like to use as a sans-serif. 
But how do I get latex to actually set the document in a sans-serif font?

Also, I am using the package `lslisting` to format code-listings. 
How can I set my document such that all code is set in a separate font, e.g. courier or any other typewriter font?

Comment: Duplicate of [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2095/627)?

Comment: It is a duplicate, but I'm not voting to close it because of the additional `lstlisting` question.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You want to change the default family to be the sans serif family.

```
\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault}
```

does exactly that.

Concerning your other question,

```
\lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily}
```

make all code to be typeset in the active typewriter family, which is by default Computer Modern Typewriter. You can change that to Courier with `\usepackage{courier}`, just as you select Helvetica for the sans family with `\usepackage{helvet}`.

Comment: You beat me by 30 seconds. +1.

Comment: great, thx, now how would i change the font family only for headlines?

Comment: \usepackage{sectsty}\allsectionsfont{\sffamily}

Comment: @lockstep: Well, you beat me by 2 minutes on the `\paragraph` spacing question. (I still posted because we propose different approaches.)