# Why are there no alternatives to TeX, or, why is TeX still used?

Tags: tex-core, latex-misc

I'm fairly new to TeX and LaTeX, having been drawn in by the *Big Idea* — creating a document programmatically.  However, my experience of TeX (and its libraries — LaTeX, ConTeXt, …) has been almost entirely unpleasant.

My impression is that TeX (*etc.*) is essentially a pile of undocumented macros (where even are *functions?*) in an unparsable syntax (I am told it's Turing-complete), that very often collapses (most error messages have a mysterious origin), with shaky support for modern frameworks (I have to *read a paper* on font naming schemes to find how to apply Helvetica?), and no serious opportunity for actual programming (as opposed to braindead markup), with a confusingly fragmented codebase (which binary, distribution, library should I use, and how do they interact?).

Given that the Big Idea is a laudable one, and that TeX and friends are far from an ideal implementation of it, I'd like to know:

**Why it is that, within the problem domain of programmatic document formatting, TeX is the only serious player?  Does no-one have an idea of how do to this better?  What would TeX look like if we were to design it from scratch?**

(Note: I'm *not* looking for a flame war; I'm looking for genuine answers.)

Comment: eegg, welcome to TeX.SX. Note that this is a Q&A site and not for discussions or even opinions, so I'm very tended to close this post as "subjective and argumentative. Note that TeX is not "a pile of undocumented macros" but very well documented in ["The TeXBook"](http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~uno/abcde.html). LaTeX and its packages come with documentation and there are dozens of books about this topic. A simple Google search for "Helvetica latex" tells you how to apply it. .....

Comment: @eegg: While the guys at TeX-SE are quite civilized and helpful, we cannot help but notice your accusatory and generally negative tone. People would be much more willing to discuss TeX deficiencies (of which there are many) if you edit your question and try to phrase it in a neutral manner. With that being said, welcome on board, and enjoy your stay!

Comment: I wouldn't call a book I have to purchase for £30+ "adequate documentation".  And that's just TeX.  [This](http://docs.python.org/py3k/) is documentation.

What about applying Helvetica to headings?  [This offhand post](http://www.kronto.org/thesis/tips/section-title.html) is the only thing I can find, and it doesn't apply to Helvetica (by which I mean the many different cryptic names for Helvetica clones).

Comment: @eegg: Surely you have perused the free resources (CTAN, TUG-UK FAQ, a few introductory tutorials and the LaTeX book on Wikibooks). The TeXbook source is free (you can compile it yourself). There are also comp.text.tex, and #latex on irc.freenode.net. Finally, there is TeX-SE. If you have a particular question that you haven't found an answer for in all these resources -- go ahead and ask, we will be happy to help. But to say that there are not enough good sources of information about TeX & Friends (from the very people that contribute to them) is disingenuous, at best.

Comment: In reply to the 'designed from scratch' part, I think that there is a key issue about how the input might look. The problem with typography is that a 'clean' separation of content and appearance is probably impossible. From what I can pick up about XML-based systems they still have to include 'cludge' information to get the right output.

Comment: Please add @MartinScharrer to your comments when you want to address me. I didn't added @eegg because the post owner gets notified anyways about comments. Note that you do not have to buy the TeXBook (which source code is on CTAN) to use LaTeX. I wouldn't compare Python or any other software programming language with a documentation preparation system like (La)TeX.

Comment: I'd point out that there are a very small number of people with the skills to both write binaries and do the typography. There have been proposals: in recent years, the obvious approach has been to consider a pure XML system. However, getting something working would be very challenging, and the question is who would do it? (No-one who's suggested it has ever had a significant chunk of code to show the way.)

Comment: @eegg: i recommend a fresh start. Instead of barging in and dismissing TeX because you can't find the answer to your question without learning a bit about the language, or because there is no analogue of the python website, ask instead: "I am a new user and am having trouble customizing the article class to make section headings in Helvetica. I have found this document but I can't really understand it. Can someone explain?"  You will get the answer and be introduced to a community very willing to help.

Comment: After pondering this all afternoon, I've come down on the side that I don't like this type of question and don't want to see it here.  If you do want "genuine answers" then please ask a genuine question.  This place is for finding _specific_ answers to _specific_ questions, not for discussions.  You could easily turn each point in your post in to a specific (and neutral) question, in which case I'd happily join in trying to convince you of the value of TeX, but I find myself not wanting to get involved in this for fear it might turn nasty.

Comment: If you're looking for TeX quality formatting but an easier to use interface, you need to pay for it; e.g. InDesign offers most of the capability of TeX with a WYSIWYG interface, but it's several hundred bucks.

Comment: @Billy: Indesign has weak scripting facilities that are about as sophisticated as writing macros for Word using VBA without access to .NET libraries.  I don't think it gives what the qner wants.

Comment: This question has been posted to Hacker News: http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=2326545

Comment: 22 up-votes and a lot of traffic. But alas, the question has been closed. Something is wrong with this picture.

Comment: @Charles: Well, yes, WYSIWYG kind of excludes things like decent macros. But those same macros are intimidating to a beginning user. I'm not saying "Indesign is superior"; rather, I'm saying "indesign is easier to use, and gets you *close* to what TeX is capable of" (i.e. it's capable of doing things like TeX's minimal raggedness line breaking algorithm).

Comment: If you want to discuss this qn and why it was closed, you might like to participate [in this meta qn I started](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1171/welcome-to-new-users-hn-edition), or visit [the Tex chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41/tex-latex-and-friends).  @Charlie: The problem the closers had was with how the qn invited vigorous argument, which is something we've decided this site is not about.  The HN thread, by contrast *is* suited to that kind of argument.

Comment: There is one alternative to LaTeX which uses much more modern ideas. It's called [Lout](http://savannah.nongnu.org/projects/lout) and it works quite well. The disadvantages are however a lack of documentation (only the official one) and you won't find any help for it on the internet. The author of Lout is currently thinking about doing another program called [Nonpareil](http://sydney.edu.au/engineering/it/~jeff/nonpareil/), but I don't know how far developed this is.

Comment: I believe what OP is asking is why hasn't been a typesystem like tex implemented in a more recent language like python, ruby, heck even Haskell - which lends itself nicely to embedded DSLs. All of these languages have nice error reporting tools, fast and tested compile times and well-documented libraries.

Comment: I think TeX is still used, because it produces still the best output you can get! But I also think that people dislike it, because it's markup is arcane and you don't have nice error reporting you expect from a modern system. My approach therefore is a little pragmatic: I use *reStructuredText* (rST) and convert it via Sphinx to LaTex. To ease this process I even wrote an online editor NoTex (available at https://notex.ch) .. it does not have error reporting yet, as it should, be I'm working on it. I think LaTex excels as long as you don't have to see it's ugly markup!

Comment: I think this is a very good question. Yes, the tone is a bit offensive, especially for diehard TeX fans. I'm a big fan of TeX, and of Knuth. Yet the question in bold is a very good one. Yes, it could be posed more constructively, but it's definitely worth discussing.

Comment: A good and honest question, and those who deem it not so might not have had the luxury of peeking outside the TeX universe,  using different programming languages, having a mindset where reflection and comparison to other ways of doing things helps you see how the way you do things can be massively improved upon. That said, my answer would be mostly this: dogma + a lack of truly knowledgeable minds that understand / program LaTeX who would want to remake it.

Comment: I recently used LuaTeX and I realised it was the only way to do something complex. There are so many clashes between packages, due to the way macros expand, that it is impossible to move on otherwise. With Lua is still a pain, but I was able to do some cool stuff. Overall TeX is a pile of garbage (sorry Donald). Problem is LaTeX is much more than TeX, and it would take years to write something better. No one will do it, there is no money, no interest in it. JavaScript is garbage as well, and so is Python, but they are mainstream, and we can't get rid of them.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

(My apologies in advance for any "too long; didn't read" sentiments -- if you only read one thing out of this, make it this link: [Best Way to Start Using LaTeX/TeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4420/best-way-to-start-using-latex-tex))

**My Non-Expert Background:**

- I started using LaTeX around 2002 to help engineering students at my university write their M.S. theses and PhD dissertations.
- For several years, I made basic modifications to an older thesis style file dating to the early 1990s, and made two or three attempts at writing one from scratch.
- I finally succeeded with a version I started in 2008, and made a lot of changes to it recently to isolate my users from the style's inner structure by default. The new style covers every feature of the old style, adds quite a bit more automation for our odd page headings in the ToC and other lists, and has around 50% fewer lines of code.

**Things I've learned:**

- Writing LaTeX documents is programming as soon as you get to even a moderate level of document requirements.
- It can be programmed badly, or programmed efficiently.
- How badly or efficiently you program it is strongly influenced by obsessive-compulsive tendencies, curiosity, and critical thinking.

As for specific issues posed:

**most error messages have a mysterious origin**

I can see where you're coming from there. You certainly don't get a clean Pythonic stack trace. There's no easy debugging tools (ConTeXt may have better support, though). Debugging is generally a process of producing minimal working examples, which either lets you identify where the problem went away as you started commenting and removing code, or at least scopes the problem down enough to where you can get expert advice more easily.

Really, this reminds me of how we'd debug Fortran code back in the day with 'echo checks' when we didn't have a good debugger (or else didn't know how to use one).

**I have to read a paper on font naming schemes to find how to apply Helvetica?**

I'm assuming this is partially hyperbole, but it does speak to the varying levels of documentation available. Some documentation is out of date, some is incomplete. Googling 'latex font' returns a pretty unpredictable range of answers, including some that are either just wrong, or outdated, or incomplete.

Googling 'latex font selection' returned other pages, including [this Wikibooks page](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Fonts), but it's not quite what you were looking for unless you wanted to use XeTeX (which was created, in part, to handle Unicode and arbitrary fonts more easily).

I did eventually search this site for font information, and found [How do I change a font document wide?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4893/how-do-i-change-a-font-document-wide) -- it didn't give a complete example, but has all the pieces there. A MWE for Helvetica by default is

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{helvet}
\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault}
\begin{document}
Hello, world.
\end{document}
```

**where even are functions?** (with a diversion into OCD territory)

I'm not sure how you define functions versus macros as such, but I can certainly define blocks of reusable code and call them. Those blocks can take varying numbers of arguments, and act accordingly. They can effectively provide default values for arguments. LaTeX's global namespace can be a hindrance, but is generally worked around by tagging local variables with a special prefix or similar.

Example: our signature sheet for the thesis committee needs one line per committee member. Some committee members have a particular title (chair or cochair), others have no particular title. Each line should also include a spot for the member to write the approval date. At one time, we had a relative **ton** of copied and pasted code that only differed in whether we were typesetting the name for `\memberone`, `\membertwo`, etc. and whether the person had a specific title.

Now, we have a single function (or macro, I guess) that takes two arguments, and can typeset any member's signature line.

```
\newcommand{\nameanddateline}[2]{% irrelevant spacing and other commands removed
  \eqparbox{name}{\hrulefill} \quad \parbox{.75in}{\hrulefill} \\ 
  \eqparbox{name}{#1\ifthenelse{\equal{#2}{}}{\relax}{, #2}}
  \quad \makebox[.75in][c]{\hfill{}Date\hfill{}} \\ 
}
```

Called as `\nameanddateline{\committeechair}{\chairtitle}` we get a signature line with the chair's title added. Called as `\nameanddateline{\memberone}{}`, we get a signature line with no title at all. In a version I'll be posting in the next few days, I even got rid of the `\memberN` parts in favor of an array of names (students would use `\renewcommand{\committeemembers}{Member 1, Member 2, ...}`, and I can iterate over the comma-separated values in `\committeemembers`.

LaTeX won't force you to write efficient or maintainable code or markup. I don't claim mine is top-tier. My Python code would possibly make you cry in anguish. But it's like any other language in regards to it being up to the programmer to decide how clean they want things to be.

**no serious opportunity for actual programming (as opposed to braindead markup)**

I'm not sure what you'd call braindead markup. There's enough programming capability in it for me to get my documents typeset in a relatively efficient fashion. I can define my own commands, I can loop over elements of a simple array defined as comma-separated values, and I have if/then/else structures. For my needs, it's worked out fine. I'd certainly prefer this to writing VBA or fighting master documents and other issues in MS Word.

There's a lot of stale information out there. There are a lot of bad habits ingrained in long-time users who haven't kept up with new packages, or haven't thought through how to write their documents more like code, and less like explicit markup. Case in point: I've got a guy who has 1700+ `\bf` commands in his dissertation, each of which throws errors in newer memoir classes by default. **All** of those commands are for defining vectors. If he had ever read any of the intermediate material that said you could define a `\bvec{}` command to do the vector formatting, he'd only have to change `\newcommand\bvec[1]{\bf #1}` to `\newcommand\bvec[1]{\bfseries #1}` once.

Similarly, a collaborator brought some odd theorem spacing to my attention. He had been working around it by including a `\vspace*` command to remove the extra space. I thought, "this can't possibly be the way it's designed to work" and my OCD kicked in. Within an hour or so, I had found a much cleaner solution using the `\qedhere` command. It's well-documented at Wikibooks, but you'd have to go look for it rather than simply implement the first fix that comes to mind.

I'm disheartened by things like this, but not shocked. Maybe my standards are too low -- just a few years ago, I had a student ask me why her professor's Fortran finite element code wouldn't compile on her system, but worked fine on his. I started writing Fortran in 1989, and I've adapted code written in the early 70's. *I didn't recognize the notation on the lines throwing errors.* One of the other faculty looked at and said, "Oh, that's [Hollerith notation](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Hollerith_constant)." That notation was deprecated in the Fortran 66 standard, and deleted entirely in Fortran 77. The original professor was still using it in 2004 or so. Why? Because it still compiled for him. There's a similar effect in some long-time LaTeX users.

**a confusingly fragmented codebase (which binary, distribution, library should I use, and how do they interact?).**

Thankfully, the fragmentation is more in theory than in practice. At least in my experience, LaTeX code generally is distribution-neutral. I've had to modify one command in my thesis style to handle two different versions of the memoir class (one from 2005 in PCTeX, and the current one on CTAN). But all I had to do was to check if a particular very simple command was defined, and if not, define it myself.

CTAN, I think, is pretty good about having clean, updated packages. Instructions or packages you get from a random Google search can obviously vary quite a lot.

Answer (score 31):

The alternatives to TeX exist: they are WYSIWYG word processors and desktop publishing programs.  And in most commercial areas they are adopted far more widely.

TeX is still used [in many academic and other fields](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/940/what-professions-use-tex-latex-besides-cs) because

- [its output is beautiful](http://www.texample.net/)
- it's free and open source
- it's gained considerable inertia in the 30 years since it's been in use, being part of the academic tradition

I'm not sure what you mean by a lack of "serious programming opportunities".  Functions and data structures are implemented as macros, yes, but I think that most of the power TeX users would call themselves programmers.

You might find some of these questions helpful in your quest for understanding the TeX way:

- [What is TeX used for?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5893/what-is-tex-used-for)
- [Why should I use LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1756/why-should-i-use-latex)
- [What are good learning resources for a LaTeX beginner?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11/what-is-the-best-book-to-start-learning-latex)

And as for putting section headings in Helvetica, it isn't that bad, but you do have to understand a few things about LaTeX and its history.  TeX predates PostScript, PDF, TrueType, and most electronic typesetting standards (as well as Unicode which is a whole new set of issues).  So its font mechanism is a little archaic.  This has been dramatically improved with the XeTeX engine, which works natively with TrueType fonts and Unicode.

Here is a sample file, which is similar to the [solution that you linked to](http://www.kronto.org/thesis/tips/section-title.html) in that it uses the [`sectsty`](http://ctan.org/pkg/sectsty) package.  This package is probably on your local TeX distribution anyway; no need to download or install.  Unlike the example you linked to you have to run this through xelatex instead of pdflatex.  Again, that executable is also probably in your local distribution too.  The advantage is the the font specification is more sane.

```
\documentclass{article}
\title{Helvectica section headings}
% TEX.SE \url{}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily{\phv}{Helvetica}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\allsectionsfont{\phv}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section{First section}

\lipsum[1-3]

\section{Second section}

\lipsum[4-5]

\end{document}
```

Comment: "Functions and data structures are implemented as macros, yes" -- I guess an important part of my question is, *why*?  Is this a design choice?  Is it possible to write real code purely in macros without it being incomprehensible?

Comment: @eegg: You simply don't get functions in a macro language, in general. There are some areas where this can be done (see for example http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11425/), but this is not general. On the 'incomprehensible' question, I feel we do a good job with expl3, while others do a good job without it. However, if you're expecting function-like approaches then your bound to be confused: TeX simply does not work that way.

Comment: @eegg: There is a point of history that you may not be away of. Programming does not have a base of "functions" surround by weird-stuff-like-macros-that-only-eggheads-use. Historically, procedural programming (fortran, c, etc) and functional program (lisp and derivatives) came together very early on, and macro substitution languages came shortly thereafter. Then they all developed in parallel. TeX is part of a honorable language tradition that goes back to the '60s, and Knuth a number of models to base his design on.

Comment: @dmckee, Yes, but surely eegg is right: the fact that it's a macro language makes it impossible to write good, comprehensible code.  Isn't it just poor design?

Comment: @Neil: I find macro languages harder than imperative ones (probably because I don't use them as much), but not "impossible" or even close. They do require a change of POV, however, and if you haven't gotten that yet you *will* struggle.

Comment: @dmckee: Can you really, cleanly accomplish abstraction, data structures, loops, recursion, or object-oriented programming in macro languages?

Comment: @Matthew: I can't get your example to compile here. xetex foo.tex gives -> ! Undefined control sequence.
l.1 \documentclass
                  {article}

Comment: @Neil G: and you don't need any of this to typeset a document, no typesetting system does provide such capabilities, no markup language does. TeX has macros as a powerful way to aid in typesetting your documents, period. People do use it for more than what it was really for, but it is hardly a design fault. The same happens with m4 macro language for example.

Comment: @Faheem: try `xelatex` (now do you know why `documentclass` is undefined?)

Comment: @Khaled: I think that's only true for the simplest things like style and inserting figures, etc.  As soon as you want to programmatically generate images (like with tikz) or have "macros" that conditionally do different things based on where they're invoked, it becomes almost impossible to do with macros.

Comment: @Neil G: indeed, and people shouldn't be doing that. TeX is not a drawing program (even Knuth is using MetaPost for his diagrams), but if they choose to do so then they shouldn't complain (and indeed, people who do such things are usually happy using macros, I recall one calling it "art", but I call it black magic myself). TeX's macro were never intended for extending TeX's functionality, Knuth thought people extend TeX the program instead.

Comment: @Khaled: I think that's shortsighted of Knuth.  Would you say the same thing about C++ or Python: that you should extend the language rather than the libraries?  In fact, they're taking the opposite approach: Python is obsessed with keeping a simple language and having many imports, and C++'s newest updates (C++0x) have changes meant to facilitate writing libraries.  The advantage of writing libraries over extending the language is that when you write your library, your change is immediately distributable, and no one can veto your work.

Comment: @Neil G: TeX is never meant to please everyone, once it was good enough to typeset Knuth books he was very reluctant to add any new features. Also, again TeX's primary and sole purpose is to do good typesetting not to be programmable/extensible. Knuth idea of "project specific TeX versions" failed indeed and people kept using macros in ways he never envisioned, and that is why we have luatex now; a truly extensible TeX engine with real programming language.

Comment: The alternatives to TeX indeed exist and they are not necessary WYSIWYG. Besides well known Groff and defunct Scribe by Brian Reid, I would warmly recommend Lout http://savannah.nongnu.org/projects/lout/

Comment: @PredragPunosevac: Thanks for telling me about lout.  That would be worth an answer in its own right.

Comment: Re: the first sentence, "The alternatives to TeX exist: they are WYSIWYG word processors and desktop publishing programs": The question was asking for alternatives *"within the problem domain of programmatic document formatting,"* so this isn't answering the question. WYSIWYG wp's and desktop publishing programs don't provide programmatic document formatting.

Answer (score 31):

*Why it is that, within the problem domain of programmatic document formatting, TeX is the only serious player?*

It's not obvious to me what you mean by this, but on the face of it, the presupposition isn't true.  Based on Java, there are two exceedingly capable tools for generating PDFs: Open Office has a completely programmable back-end, whilst i-Text, a Java library for creating PDFs, allows almost complete coverage of PDF features, and is more capable in this respect than can be done with Tex engines (try putting a digital signature on your Latex'd letters).  Both of these support a method of generating documents similar to [HTML::Template](http://search.cpan.org/~samtregar/HTML-Template-2.9/Template.pm) where the document template and code are kept separate, which many regard as cleaner and more maintainable than how Latex documents are often written.  FWIW, recent versions of Word allow VBA to access .NET libraries, allowing a quite high level of programmatic sophistication in document creation as well.

The strength of the Tex family doesn't lie, IMO, in its feature list, although with respect to microtypography, none of the above systems are competitive with Luatex, but rather in the ethos of document preparation and styling.  Knuth's creation was extraordinarily rich.  I have lost count of the number of ascii notations for mathematics whose authors believe it to be better than Knuth's: none in fact are.  Knuth did not attempt to give the most general model, but just one sufficient for mathematicians writing for publication, but his model has weathered well and has been hugely influential on later designs, which generally have learned only some of the lessons on offer.

It takes time to become competent with any of the Tex systems, but once you have, it is a very natural way of preparing texts.  Tex is really only hard when you want fine control over output, and then *all* systems are hard.  The semantics of macros are often complained about and they are tricky, but it is not easy to find a computational mechanism that fits so smoothly into text.

So there are alternatives, and the Tex family has deep and distinctive strengths.

Answer (score 26):

TeX is still used, simply because there is no alternative. It is far from being perfect, and there is at least a grain of truth in most, if not all of your claims.
But these are, at the end of the day, unimportant.

If you need a document which requires even the slightest programmatic bit, or any level of sophistication, LaTeX, though not-ideal, is simply the best, and is likely to stay so for many more years.

I believe most users (maybe not so in this site) just turn a blind eye to the not so elegant features, and produce amazing documents in no time. The very friendly bunch here does not see these not-so-elegant portions as being so annoying. To most, these are just riddles to enjoy, just like cryptic crossword puzzle.

You do not really have to put your mind to the tough/complicated/riddle/annoying basics. You would better ignore these, at least as a starter. Read the "not so short guide", and be happy with it. If you need something extra, you just go and find a package that does that, and the quest is usually
quite easy.

The difficult part is in programming something new, something that cannot be found in existing package. There are experts of this dark art: the rest of us just watch them do their wizardry with awe. Luckily, the cases where you really need to do this kind of programming are very rare: chances are that you will find it was done.

Answer (score 23):

Presupposition failure.

First, people are trying to make TeX better for example the [LaTeX3](http://www.latex-project.org/latex3.html) and [LuaTeX](http://www.luatex.org/) projects. (These aren't quite rebuilding LaTeX from scratch, but they're close)

Second, there are alternatives, like [DocBook](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DocBook). In fact, many markup language projects could be seen in this light. What is HTML doing if it is not creating documents programmatically?

A little less facetiously, why *is* TeX still popular? There's a certain amount of "if it ain't broke...": A lot of people know how to use TeX and any new project would have a hard time convincing anyone to use it.

I think your general question could be ask of any big code project. Why is PHP the way it is? Why does HTML work like *so*? Why don't we just throw it all away and start from scratch? Because that is [rarely a good idea.](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000069.html)

Comment: My understanding of LuaTeX is that it's just embedding Lua into TeX.  HTML (and currently DocBook IMO) have little understanding of *physical* documents.  As for starting from scratch, I see it being done all the time (hence the hundreds (thousands?) of programming languages around); I wasn't really asking whether this is a "good idea", but why it isn't done.

Comment: One thing I can see that fits the description of "TeX from scratch" is [Lout](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/lout/).  It seems pleasurable to work with (being more like a Real Language), and it surprises me that its userbase is so impressively small.

Comment: The long-term LaTeX3 goal is to reimplement all of LaTeX2e. However, this is surprisingly complex (there are many unsolved problems).

Comment: @eegg: See also ANT (http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=ant), which does seem to have run into the ground but is I guess somewhat in the area you are interest in.

Comment: @eegg: *LuaTeX is ... just embedding Lua into TeX* - Just this is not a small thing: it has profound consequences for how one can programmatically generate documents, with much of the innards of the backend made available.  Luatex also standardises on Unicode and introduces microtypography that is equal to that in Adobe's top-end products and better than everything else, among several other new features.  Context Mk4 makes much use of Luatex to do what it does.  Context Mk4 is well suited to typesetting Docbook manuscripts.

Comment: I really wish people would leave comments explaining why they downvoted.

Answer (score 16):

From my layman's perspective, you could get somewhat far (?) by implementing the Knuth-Plass line-breaking algorithm along with the Liang's hyphenation algorithm in your general-purpose programming language of choice as an encapsulated DSL for typesetting. You'd almost certainly want to implement the math material interpretation in a similar way to TeX (compare to XML dialects, for instance, where it would be too tedious to write math by hand).

But what surprises me, as a relatively newcomer to TeX, is the number of questions posted to this site which start off with the expectation of TeX being a general-purpose programming language. I don't think that is a good approach at all.

TeX is a *typesetting system*, first and foremost!

Answer (score 14):

I guess my overall answer would be 'critical mass'. Others have pointed out that most typesetting is actually done using other tools, and that TeX is mainly used in certain area. Within those areas, there is a lot of experience of how to get the results people want. Thus any new approach needs to supersede what can already be done, which is not easy. From my own experience with LaTeX3, I'd say that change even within the LaTeX world is a tough challenge.

Answer (score 14):

You should have a look to LuaTeX :

- Inclusion of Lua as an embedded
  scripting language;
- Native support of Unicode;
- Supporting modern font formats such
  as TrueType and OpenType;
- And more.

Comment: Personally, I'm not really a TeXy, but my company has a product called [DocScape](http://www.docscape.de/opencms/web/docscape/en/home/) which implements a data-driven publishing tool on top of Tex which I thought might be of interest to you or others reading this.