# Latex -> html with mathematical equations for accessibility to generate MathML

Tags: equations, accessibility, mathml, latexml

Edit, original question below - I would like to simplify the question to the following:

- **What is the best way to take a LaTeX input file, which includes matrices and vectors in formulae and make it accessible?**

Below I describe what I have done so far, which involves conversion to a web document with MathML for the equations.

I now know that Firefox supports MathML natively, but Chrome does not, which confused me somewhat.

I would really appreciate any answers/suggestions/comments - and I very much appreciate all the comments so far

From these I have learnt that MathML can be rendered with MathJax on browsers like Chrome that do not natively support MathML, (though I don't really understand exactly how to do this.)

---

---

Original posting.

First, please note the following points with regard to previous questions related to this topic

I have made progress with many thanks to contributors to the following questions/answers;

- [LaTeX to MathML conversion: tools, limitations, and approaches?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/227195/latex-to-mathml-conversion-tools-limitations-and-approaches)
- [LaTeX accessibility](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19279/latex-accessibility)
- [Converting LaTeX to HTML but keeping equations as LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/185791/converting-latex-to-html-but-keeping-equations-as-latex)

I am also aware of

- [A guide on how to produce accessible PDF files?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/261537/a-guide-on-how-to-produce-accessible-pdf-files)

I am aware that accessibility can mean different things to different people.

The particular issue that I am asking about here is about making equations accessible - and in particular generating some output that can be read by screen readers when it comes to equations.

I have several PDF documents that I generate from LaTeX files, which include equations including matrices, vectors etc.

I want to be able to generate **accessible** or at least more accessible versions of these documents from the same LaTeX files. From what I can see a good way to go is to use LaTeX to MathML converters. I am assuming in doing this is that if MathML is pretty much the standard for accessibility for equations. This is what I have found from websearching.

If I can convert equations from LaTeX documents to MathML standard then screen readers should be able to read the MathML equations and this should at least improve the accessibility of the documents.

I have generated the file `math_test.tex` to test the process **given below** at the bottom of this question.

I have used following commands to generate webfiles...

```
mk4ht mzlatex math_test.tex "html,mathplayer"  
latexml math_test.tex |latexmlpost --dest=math_test.html -
```

(using mk4ht version 1.1 and latexml version 0.8.4 - both on debian linux - the mk4ht might be a bit old, but the latexml is the newest due to issue with the debian repository for latexml, which appears to be [a known issue](https://github.com/brucemiller/LaTeXML/issues/877))

The results are a bit variable and critically depend on the web browser that I use to view the files... - multiple screen shots below show the results and the source LaTeX code is also below. - in brief Firefox does a good job, but Chrome seems to lose 'vertical spacing'. Latexml worked better for me than mk4ht, but I am aware that there may be a version issue for mk4ht

My **Questions**...

- the best results are found with latexml and firefox browser - is there something that I am doing wrong which means that different browsers show different results? The **firefox** version with latexml looks best, but I will need to try to make it impossible to view with **chrome** to make it accessible if that makes sense (see below)
- Am I missing something - do you have a better suggestion of how to generate more accessible files - particularly documents with readable equations?

Not sure why the webbrowsers behave so differently, but clearly Chrome is an issue and I have not tested IE/Edge/Safari... - I am wondering if everyone has been developing lateml/mk4ht to Firefox - any thoughts on this would be interesting. Given the much better results with Firefox I am wondering if I need to try to put suitable conditional/if statements at the beginning of the html to prevent them being read by other web browsers - or maybe just loading the pdf file instead.

---

**The PDF file looks like this:**
[image]

---

**Best fit - `latexml` (0.8.4) gives the following `.html` file in Firefox**
[image]

**`latexml` (0.8.4) gives the following `.html` file in chrome**
[image]

---

**`mk4ht` (v1.1) gives the following `.xht` in Firefox**
[image]

**`mk4ht` (v1.1) gives the following `.xht` in Chrome**
[image]

---

**LaTeX source document**

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
\centerline{\textbf{\large{Mathematical expressions}}}
\begin{enumerate}
\item Vectors $\mathbf u$, $\mathbf a$ and $\mathbf b$:
  \begin{align}
    \mathbf u &= \begin{pmatrix} -2\\-1\end{pmatrix}
  & \mathbf a &= \begin{pmatrix} -3\\1\end{pmatrix}
  & \mathbf b &= \begin{pmatrix} 1\\3\end{pmatrix}
  \end{align}
 $\mathbf u = \alpha \mathbf a + \beta \mathbf b \qquad$  Norm:$|| \mathbf u||$.
  \begin{align}
    \hat{\mathbf u} &= \lambda \mathbf a = {\langle\mathbf a, \mathbf u\rangle \over \langle\mathbf a, \mathbf a\rangle} \mathbf a 
                    =   {\begin{pmatrix}-3\\1\end{pmatrix}\cdot\begin{pmatrix}-2\\-1\end{pmatrix} \over \begin{pmatrix}-3\\1\end{pmatrix} \cdot \begin{pmatrix}-3\\1\end{pmatrix} }\mathbf a =  { 5 \over 10 }\mathbf a =
    { 1 \over 2 }\mathbf a = \begin{pmatrix}-1.5\\0.5\end{pmatrix}
  \end{align}
  
\item Matrices
\begin{align*}
\begin{pmatrix}1&3+2i\\3-2i&4\end{pmatrix} &&
{\rm det}{\mathbf A}&= 
\begin{vmatrix}3&4&7\\2&-2&1\\1&2&5\end{vmatrix}
&
\begin{vmatrix}x&1&1\\1&x&1\\1&1&x \end{vmatrix}
&= (x-1)^2(x+2)
\end{align*}
\item  $ a_1 \ge 0 \qquad p(x) = p_0+p_1x+p_2x^2+p_3x^3+p_4x^4+p_5x^5$
\item Transformations:
\begin{align*}
    T:\mathbb R^3 &\rightarrow \mathbb R^2&  \text{where}\quad  
T  \begin{pmatrix}a_1\\a_2\\a_3\end{pmatrix} =  \begin{pmatrix}a_1a_2\\a_1a_3\end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
    T:P_3 &\rightarrow M_{22}  &  \text{where}\quad  
T  \begin{pmatrix}a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+a_3x^3\end{pmatrix} =  \begin{pmatrix}a_1&a_2\\a_3&a_1-a_0\end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Have you tried `tex4ht` with `MathJax` (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/68916/convert-latex-to-mathjax-html)? I think MathJax provides some nice [accessibility support](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/basic/accessibility.html).

Comment: @AlanXiang - many thanks for the comment... so I guess you are suggesting trying `make4ht filename.tex "mathml,mathjax"` - I will try that.... .. great to hear about that - so just to be clear `MathJax` would be an alternative to `MathML` is that correct?

Comment: You can take a look at `MathJax`'s [website](https://www.mathjax.org/). It is a high-level library to display math equations on browsers. It has multiple display backends, e.g. SVG, HTML+CSS, MathML, etc. With MathJax, you can simply type math equations in HTML in LaTeX syntax and MathJax's Javascript will render them for you. Here is a [MathJax test page](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~yujiali/test/mathjax.html).

Comment: MathJaX isn't an _alternative_ to MathML. It can use MathML as an input, and this is better for accessibility since you still have the MathML for those that need it.  What MathJaX does is _render_ the mathematics for those browsers that do not yet have decent MathML support of their own.  So your best route is to convert to MathML and then serve the page with MathJaX loaded.

Comment: This does not sound as a LaTeX question but more an issue in Chrome browser. Further than this I think accessibility for formulas is very difficult if not impossible to achieve. We simply miss language for complicated formulas.

Comment: @AndrewStacey - many thanks I really appreciate the comment. -- ok so MathJaX makes the MathML 'look right', but we still need the MathML for screen reading.

Comment: @tanGIS - I agree that making equations accessible is very difficult, particularly say for a 4x4 matrix with 16 elements. The reason that I am working on this is to try to make my documents as accessible as possible --- I know now that the problems with Chrome are because it does not natively support MathML. -- I have just edited the question to make it clear that the focus is to make a LaTeX document with equations as accessible as possible.

Comment: Hi, I am Tex4ht and make4ht developer. I am on mobile now, so I cannot test anything or give detailed answer. But generally, it is best to use make4ht filename.tex "mathml,mathjax". It enables use of custom commmands unsupported by mathjax and cross-referencing.

Comment: @michal.h21 - many thanks for your reply. I appreciate it. -- the main issue I seem to have with the mk4ht i used (v1.1) was that the brackets of the vectors/matrices seemed to disappear - any suggestions would be very helpful

Comment: I will be out.of computer until the end of this week, so I cannot unfortunatelly answer this now. You can try to report this issue on TeX4ht issue tracker, so I can fix it when I will be back from my vacation. You can find the tracker here: https://tug.org/tex4ht/. Alternatively, you can report it on make4ht GitHub

Comment: Possibly useful: http://www.csun.edu/~hcmth008/mathml/acc_tutorial.pdf

Comment: @Ross - many thanks for this link

Comment: @michal.h21 - many thanks - I generated a bug report

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I thought I fixed fences not so long ago, when I removed most of instances of the deprecated  element in the MathML configuration.  should be used instead. What I missed is that the whole expression must be in enclosed , otherwise the fenced parentheses are not rendered correctly.

It should be fixed in the TeX4ht sources now. [Here is the updated mathml.4ht](https://gist.github.com/michal-h21/300deb3540174eb285d6ec41c28eb844) file you can try.

Btw, it is best to use

```
make4ht math_text.tex "mathml,mathjax"
```

make4ht post-processes the generated HTML and fixes some issues especially in MathML. `mathjax` option will load MathJax, which fixes lot of rendering issues. For example it can display our wrong MathML code correctly even without the fix.

This is how is the file rendered in Firefox without MathJax:

[image: plain]

And this one with MathJax:

[image: mathjax]

You can see that it uses nicer fonts and in addition it works also in other browsers than Firefox.

Comment: Ahoj Michal, many thanks for your answer and for fixing make4ht, really impressive work - I have started a bounty to give to this answer for the great work you have done on this.

Comment: @tom oh, thanks! it was not hard to fix, I just had to reread one section in the MathML specification :)

Answer (score 2):

One option is to write [Rmarkdown](https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/) as an `.Rmd` file and compile in `RStudio` to an `HTML` file. The `Rmarkdown` workflow is:

[image: Rmarkdown workflow]

Downstream of the `.Rmd` file, all the processing happens automatically in `RStudio`.

This is the Rmd file:

```
---
title: ""
author: ""
date: ""
output: 
  html_document:
    pandoc_args: "--mathml"
    keep_tex: true
header-includes:
  - \usepackage{amsmath}
  - \usepackage{amssymb}
---

## Mathematical expressions

1. Vectors $\mathbf u$, $\mathbf a$ and $\mathbf b$:
  \begin{align}
    \mathbf u &= \begin{pmatrix} -2\\-1\end{pmatrix}
  & \mathbf a &= \begin{pmatrix} -3\\1\end{pmatrix}
  & \mathbf b &= \begin{pmatrix} 1\\3\end{pmatrix}
  \end{align}
  
<br>
  
$\begin{aligned}
\quad \mathbf u &= \alpha \mathbf a + \beta \mathbf b \qquad  \text{Norm:}|| \mathbf u|| 
\end{aligned}$

<br>

\begin{align}
    \hat{\mathbf u} 
       &= \lambda \mathbf a \quad 
       = {\langle\mathbf a, \mathbf u\rangle \over \langle\mathbf a, \mathbf a\rangle} \mathbf a 
       = {\begin{pmatrix}-3\\1\end{pmatrix}\cdot\begin{pmatrix}-2\\-1\end{pmatrix} \over \begin{pmatrix}-3\\1\end{pmatrix} \cdot \begin{pmatrix}-3\\1\end{pmatrix} }\mathbf a 
       =  { 5 \over 10 }\mathbf a 
       =  { 1 \over 2 }\mathbf a = \begin{pmatrix}-1.5\\0.5\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}

<br>

2. **Matrices**

\begin{align*}
\begin{pmatrix}1&3+2i\\3-2i&4\end{pmatrix} &&
{\rm det}{\mathbf A}&=
\begin{vmatrix}3&4&7\\2&-2&1\\1&2&5\end{vmatrix}
&
\begin{vmatrix}x&1&1\\1&x&1\\1&1&x \end{vmatrix}
&= (x-1)^2(x+2)
\end{align*}

<br>

3. $\begin{aligned} a_1 \ge 0 \qquad p(x) = p_0+p_1x+p_2x^2+p_3x^3+p_4x^4+p_5x^5 \end{aligned}$

<br>

4. **Transformations:**

\begin{align*}
    T:\mathbb R^3 &\rightarrow \mathbb R^2&  \text{where}\quad
T  \begin{pmatrix}a_1\\a_2\\a_3\end{pmatrix} =  \begin{pmatrix}a_1a_2\\a_1a_3\end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
    T:P_3 &\rightarrow M_{22}  &  \text{where}\quad
T  \begin{pmatrix}a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+a_3x^3\end{pmatrix} =  \begin{pmatrix}a_1&a_2\\a_3&a_1-a_0\end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}
```

The syntax is very close to what one writes in a `.tex` file. Switch `html_document` in the YAML header with `pdf_document` and you can get the corresponding pdf.

This is the HTML output:

[image: HTML output]

To have our HTML is written with `mathml`, we add `--mathml` to the arguments passed to `pandoc`. This is what we see at the top of the HTML file:

[image]

In this workflow, `knitr` produces a `.tex` file. As we can see, it is unremarkable, and very closely resembles the OP's original `latex` code, just adding elements like the `enumerate` environment.

```
\begin{document}
\centerline{\textbf{\large{Mathematical expressions}}}
\begin{enumerate}
\item Vectors $\mathbf u$, $\mathbf a$ and $\mathbf b$:
  \begin{align}
    \mathbf u &= \begin{pmatrix} -2\\-1\end{pmatrix}
  & \mathbf a &= \begin{pmatrix} -3\\1\end{pmatrix}
  & \mathbf b &= \begin{pmatrix} 1\\3\end{pmatrix}
  \end{align}
 $\mathbf u = \alpha \mathbf a + \beta \mathbf b \qquad$  Norm:$|| \mathbf u||$.
  \begin{align}
    \hat{\mathbf u} &= \lambda \mathbf a = {\langle\mathbf a, \mathbf u\rangle \over \langle\mathbf a, \mathbf a\rangle} \mathbf a
                    =   {\begin{pmatrix}-3\\1\end{pmatrix}\cdot\begin{pmatrix}-2\\-1\end{pmatrix} \over \begin{pmatrix}-3\\1\end{pmatrix} \cdot \begin{pmatrix}-3\\1\end{pmatrix} }\mathbf a =  { 5 \over 10 }\mathbf a =
    { 1 \over 2 }\mathbf a = \begin{pmatrix}-1.5\\0.5\end{pmatrix}
  \end{align}

\item Matrices
\begin{align*}
\begin{pmatrix}1&3+2i\\3-2i&4\end{pmatrix} &&
{\rm det}{\mathbf A}&=
\begin{vmatrix}3&4&7\\2&-2&1\\1&2&5\end{vmatrix}
&
\begin{vmatrix}x&1&1\\1&x&1\\1&1&x \end{vmatrix}
&= (x-1)^2(x+2)
\end{align*}
\item  $ a_1 \ge 0 \qquad p(x) = p_0+p_1x+p_2x^2+p_3x^3+p_4x^4+p_5x^5$
\item Transformations:
\begin{align*}
    T:\mathbb R^3 &\rightarrow \mathbb R^2&  \text{where}\quad
T  \begin{pmatrix}a_1\\a_2\\a_3\end{pmatrix} =  \begin{pmatrix}a_1a_2\\a_1a_3\end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
    T:P_3 &\rightarrow M_{22}  &  \text{where}\quad
T  \begin{pmatrix}a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+a_3x^3\end{pmatrix} =  \begin{pmatrix}a_1&a_2\\a_3&a_1-a_0\end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}
\end{enumerate}
```

Comment: This is an interesting answer, many thanks. The output looks great with this method. The issue that i have is that I have more than 100 pages of different LaTeX files that I want to convert to `html` with `mathml` and conversion from `.tex` to `.rmd` would be a significant undertaking, though I take your point that the `.rmd` code is very similar to the `.tex` code

Comment: @Tom. I understand that perspective very well. I have learned that it is important to think about the desired output before writing any code, as having to rewrite is tedious and not a constructive use of time. My general rule is that if I am producing pdf only, I will write LaTeX. If I am going to need HTML, I will write Rmarkdown. A critical motivation for me was when I needed an efficient tool for creating web site content. Rmarkdown provides a very clean and reliable work flow for doing that.It is widely used by data scientists.

Comment: note that `make4ht` supports Rmarkdown too, as well as Rtex and Rnw. So you can use R and LaTeX together for the HTML output. It is true that it can be tricky, especially when you use lot of packages that may clash between each other. It is best to work on the HTML conversion from the beginning, it is much more work when you have complete book. Even small issues are much more difficult to identify and fix at that moment.

Comment: Ross, thanks for the useful comment. The documents I have been written over the years in LaTeX as PDF files and I want to keep producing them as PDF files, just looking for a way to have them as html as well as PDF. (maybe that is wanting too much)

Answer (score 1):

According to https://dlmf.nist.gov/LaTeXML/manual/usage/usage.single.html#SS0.SSS0.P5, you can pass the option `--javascript=LaTeXML-maybeMathJax.js` to latexmlpost and it will call the appropriate MathJax library if the browser doesn't support MathML.  More specifically, calling

```
latexml myfile --dest=myfile.xml
latexmlpost --javascript=LaTeXML-maybeMathJax.js myfile.xml --dest=myfile.html
```

Loads the provided javascript file which loads the cloudflare cdn MathJax with the configuration `MML_HTMLorMML`.  In Chrome, I end up with:

[image: output]

Comment: mamy thanks I appreciate it, that is really helpful.