# How do I switch all fonts in a document to a sans-serif family?

Tags: fonts, sans-serif

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Simplest way to typeset entire document in sans serif (Helvetica)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2095/simplest-way-to-typeset-entire-document-in-sans-serif-helvetica)

I use document class `article` and included

```
\usepackage{helvet}
```

I now begin my document with

```
\begin{document}
  \sf     % select sans-serif family
  % ... text here ...
```

Most text is indeed *sans-serif*. But fur example the **footnotes** and `{\bf bold text}` is not.

Let me summarize a test document:

```
\documentclass[12pt,english]{article}
\usepackage{helvet}
\begin{document}
  \sf  % select sans-serif family
  \title{Document title is sans-serif, fine}
  \maketitle

  Normal Text is sans-serif, too.  % sans-serif, ok.

  {\bf This bold text should be sans-serif, too.} % bold, but roman!!!
\end{document}
```

Comment: Avoid using `\sf`, `\bf`, etc. Use `\textsf`, `\textbf`, etc. instead.

Comment: @Raphink: Ok, will do for the future. But this was not the issue here, neither did it help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This assumes you have no math in your document.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{helvet} % or \usepackage{tgheros}

%%% we want that the default font family is sans serif
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{\sfdefault}

\begin{document}

This is sans serif; \textbf{this also} and this again.

\end{document}
```

Don't use the old two letter commands such as `\sf` or `\bf`.

Comment: I mean is there any way (or package) to put sans serif into maths?

Comment: @HarishKumar Not with Helvetica or clones thereof, if one wants a nice result. There are no (free) math fonts that accompany it.

Comment: Oh. very bad. :(

Comment: Very good. Luckily, no math here. If it there were, I'd like it to stay in roman anyway -- it just looks better. The constraints on the font family for the document are not mine, of course. Who would define a sans-serif font for a long text? Oh, I forgot to mention: It's supposed to be "Arial"... now you know where such directives are brewed up ;-) I don't mind, though -- those kitchens will not recognize the differences to Helvetica.