# Beamer fonts in article

Tags: beamer, fonts

I would like to use `beamer`'s fonts in a standard LaTeX article.

Something like:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
bla
$bla$
\end{document}
```

But with everything with `beamer`'s fonts inside?

I have found how to change the math fonts only (using [`sansmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/sansmath) package) but I would like to change also the text fonts.

Comment: So you want everything in sans serif. Does (the first line of) Lev's answer to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2095/simplest-way-to-typeset-entire-document-in-sans-serif-helvetica help?

Comment: Yes it works (but this does not change all fonts, so I need to combine this + the sansmath package).

Thanks a lot

Comment: In presentations with »[beamer](http://ctan.org/pkg/beamer)« I prefer »[cmbright](http://ctan.org/pkg/cmbright)«. Perhaps that could also be an option for you in an article. There are some other [sans serif fonts in the LaTeX font catalogue](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/sansseriffonts.html).

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Care to answer?