# fontspec – sans-serif as main font?

Tags: fonts, luatex, fontspec, sans-serif

`fontspec` defines the commands

```
\setmainfont{font name}[font features]
\setsansfont{font name}[font features]
\setmonofont{font name}[font features]
```

to set the document’s default fonts. However, if I use a sans-serif font as the main font, e. g. `\setmainfont{Latin Modern Sans}`, `\rmfamily` is redefined as Latin Modern Sans, so I lose the ability to specify a separate serif font. Of course, I could set the serif font with `\setsansfont`, but then I have the fonts all backwards.

Shouldn’t there also be a command `\setseriffont`? I don't think a “main” font should necessarily always be a serif font. If this is intended, what is the best way to have a sans-serif font as the default font, but still have a serif font defined as `\rmfamily`?

(This is unrelated to [“What is the simplest way to typeset an entire document in sans-serif?”](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2095). I already explained that I could typeset the document in a sans-serif font by using `\setmainfont`. This question is about the semantics of the command `\setmainfont`, which doesn’t seem to imply any specific font characteristics from its name, compared to `\setsansfont`, `\rmfamily` and `\sffamily` – see also [the comment by Will Robertson](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/211394#comment494584_211394).)

Comment: You could just use the `\newfontfamily` command; e.g., `\newfontfamily\garamond[<options>]{EB Garamond}`.

Comment: Well, yes, from a practical point of view, but wouldn't that be an oversight in the design of the `fontspec` package?

Comment: I see what you're saying, but I'll let those responsible for the design weigh in.

Comment: I have toyed in the past with renaming `\setsansfont` to `\setaltfont` (or similar) but never got around to it. `\setromanfont` became `\setmainfont` many many years ago because ‘roman’ isn't a good descriptor when you're writing Greek, e.g. Perhaps `\setseriffont` would have been a better idea, but I didn't think of it at the time `:)`

Comment: That's the way LaTeX is designed. However, if you use a sans serif font as the main document font, no part of it should use a serif font.

Comment: @Socob Just to point out, now the syntax is `\setsomefont{font name}[font features]` with the features at the end.

Comment: @HenriMenke I updated the question.

Comment: @Socob No, it's not unrelated, it's a duplicate.  Compare the accepted answer here and over there.

Comment: @HenriMenke Just because two questions can be solved with the same answer doesn’t mean that the questions themselves are the same.

Comment: @Socob No, you're just asking the wrong question.  You think that switching the font of the whole document to sans-serif is somehow related to `fontspec`, when in fact it isn't.  There is a generic way which is completely independent of the font or how you load it and that is answered in the duplicate.

Comment: @HenriMenke Whatever. I see you’ve already made up your mind and are not interested in actual arguments.

Comment: @WillRobertson You could still rename it to `\setseriffont` and use `\setmainfont` as an alias for backwards-compatibility.

Comment: @henri I think I’d rather re-advertise \setromanfont than add another alias. I’ll keep thinking about it as I do want to add a couple small things to fontspec this summer. (Australian time)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
```

That is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman}
\setsansfont{Latin Modern Sans}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\begin{document}
  abc
  \textrm{abc}
  \textsf{abc}
\end{document}
```

[image: sans and serif]

Comment: `\textsc{}` is not working with this settings. How do I achieve its usual behaviour?

Answer (score 10):

If it helps to keep everything clear, you can use the `\setromanfont` command instead of `\setmainfont`, although the fontspec manual doesn't mention it:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setromanfont{Latin Modern Roman}
\setsansfont{Latin Modern Sans}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\begin{document}
  abc
  \textrm{abc}
  \textsf{abc}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why won't it work if I also set a mono font?