# What is paxcommands?

Tags: document-classes, package-options, class-options

I've been writing my own class and all the tutorials I've found use the following command to handle font options:

```
\DeclareOption{sansserif}{
  \PassOptionsToPackage{\CurrentOption}{paxcommands}
}
```

The problem is that if I use my class with the `sansserif` option, nothing changes.

Do I need to define `paxcommands` somewhere or how can I make it work?

Comment: The only mentions I can find of `paxcommands` seems to come from https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Creating_Packages, have you seen it elsewhere? Probably just a dummy package name used in the Wikibook.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. It's on [github](https://github.com/danielchatfield/latex-stuff/blob/master/supervision/supervision.cls), and in some tutorials and shell classes I've used.

Comment: I think I saw that as well, but given the identical syntax, and that that class on GitHub is almost two years newer than the [first appearance](https://en.wikibooks.org/w/index.php?title=LaTeX/Creating_Packages&direction=next&oldid=2477296) of `paxcommands` in the Wikibook, I'm inclined to guess that Daniel Chatfield took the example from the Wikibook, and never removed those unused parts. That is pure conjecture though. As @campa says, there should be a package called `paxcommands`, but Google for "paxcommands.sty" and you'll find nothing. Not CTAN, not GitHub, or anywhere else Google looks.

Comment: Looking again at the Wikibook, I suspect that the package name should have been `custom` instead of `paxcommands`, given the description of making a `custom.sty` package that appears first on that same page.

Comment: `custom.sty` has a `sans` option (not `sansserif`), and also a `neverindent` option. I'm going to edit the Wikibook, to fix this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As campa mentioned in a comment, `\PassOptionsToPackage{<list of options>}{<package name>}` passes the options given in the first argument to the package given in the second. Hence, there should have been a `paxcommands.sty` somewhere. No such package exists on CTAN, GitHub, or anywhere else Google can look.

While `paxcommands` occurs in code 17 places on GitHub, all those occurrences are similar or identical to [the one you refer to](https://github.com/danielchatfield/latex-stuff/blob/master/supervision/supervision.cls). I'm fairly certain that the origin is a (somewhat) [bad edit made to the LaTeX Wikibook](https://en.wikibooks.org/w/index.php?title=LaTeX/Creating_Packages) in January 2013. None of the 17 files on GitHub predate this.

What the code on the Wikibook *should* have said is most likely

```
%% Custom package options
\DeclareOption{sans}{
  \PassOptionsToPackage{\CurrentOption}{custom}
}
\DeclareOption{neverindent}{
  \PassOptionsToPackage{\CurrentOption}{custom}
}
```

where `custom` is the name of the custom package that is described [on that same page](https://en.wikibooks.org/w/index.php?title=LaTeX/Creating_Packages#Creating_your_own_package). `custom.sty` defines both a `sans` option (which just does [`\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2095)) and a `neverindent` option, for setting the paragraph indentation to zero.

Note further that the Wikibook had `\RequirePackage{custom}` near the end of that class.

(I have submitted an edit, which is waiting for review, to the Wikibook making that change.)

Comment: As you seem to know enough about this, could you tell me why `\ExecuteOptions{serif}` overrules using the option for sans serif in a class like the one on wikibooks?

Comment: @Kajsa That I don't know.