# Font of the text different of font in a figure generated by pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots, fonts

The font of my text are different of the font generated in figure in PGFplots. It is possible become these fonts be equal?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{QTAvanti}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{fp}
\usepackage{xfp}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,fpu}
\usetikzlibrary{fixedpointarithmetic}
\usetikzlibrary{math}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx} 
\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usetikzlibrary{math}



\begin{document}


\tikzmath{
\a = 0.5;
\b = 1; 
\n=20; 
}

 \tikzset{fixed point arithmetic}
 \tikzmath{
    function f(\x) {
    \y =   (2 - exp(\x));
    return \y; 
    };
    int \i;
    real \p;
    real \P;
    real \lb;
    real \up;
    \p = 0.5*(\a + \b);
    for \i in {0,1,2,...,\n}{
        \lb{\i} = \a;
        \ub{\i} = \b;
         \P{\i} = \p;
        if (f(\a) <= 1e-8 && f(\p) >= 1e-8) || (f(\a) >= 1e-8 && f(\p) <= 1e-8) 
          then {\b = \p;}
          else {\a = \p;};
       \p = (\a+\b)/2;
     };
}



\section{Introduction}

A fonte here is different of the figure generated by pgfplots....see below:
  

\vspace{2cm}  

  
\foreach \i in {0}{
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2,font=\scriptsize,declare function = {
func(\x) = 2 - exp(\x);}]
\clip (-1,-1.5) rectangle (4.5,2);
\draw[teal] plot [smooth,domain=0:1.2] ({2*\x},{func(\x)}) node[right]{$f(x)$};
\draw[->,-stealth] (-1,0) -- (3.2,0) node[right]{$x$};
\draw[->,-stealth] (0,-1.5) -- (0,1.5) node[above]{$y$}; 
\foreach \i in {0,0.5,...,1.5}{
\draw (2*\i,2pt) -- (2*\i,-2pt) node[below]{$\i$};
}
\foreach \i in {-1,-0.5,...,1}{
\draw (2pt,\i) -- (-2pt,\i) node[left,fill=white]{$\i$};
}
\draw[densely dotted] (2*\lb{\i},0) -- (2*\lb{\i},{func(\lb{\i})}) -- (0,{func(\lb{\i})});
\draw[densely dotted] (2*\ub{\i},0) -- (2*\ub{\i},{func(\ub{\i})}) -- (0,{func(\ub{\i})});
\fill[blue] (2*\P{\i},0) circle (1pt);
\fill[blue] (2*\P{\i},{func(\P{\i})}) circle (1pt);
\draw[densely dashed] (2*\P{\i},0) node[below right]{$p_{\i}$} -- (2*\P{\i},{func(\P{\i})});
\fill[red] (2*\lb{\i},0) circle (1pt);
\fill[red] (2*\ub{\i},0) circle (1pt);
\fill[teal] (2*\lb{\i},{func(\lb{\i})}) circle (1pt);
\fill[teal] (2*\ub{\i},{func(\ub{\i})}) circle (1pt);
\node (T) at (1.8,1.5) {$p_{\i}=\fpeval{round(\P{\i},8)}$};
\node (T) at (1.8,1.7) {$a_{\i}=\fpeval{round(\lb{\i},8)}$};
\node (T) at (1.8,1.9) {$b_{\i}=\fpeval{round(\ub{\i},8)}$};
\end{tikzpicture}}


\end{document}
```

See in the figure the difference:

[image]

Comment: I assume this is basically a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24035 or https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33325 or https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2095.

Comment: BTW, is there a reason why *none of your 38 questions* has an *accepted answer*? Maybe have a look at the tour: https://tex.stackexchange.com/tour ("The person who asked can mark one answer as "accepted").