# How to edit the properties of chapter and section headings (size of font, positions, indents)?

Tags: sectioning

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to set the font for a \section title (and chapter etc)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1455/how-to-set-the-font-for-a-section-title-and-chapter-etc)

How to edit the properties of `chapters`' and `sections`' headings (size of font, positions, indents) in `report` style?

Comment: @Alan Munn: I don't really know if it is a duplicate of that question. Apparently @filokalos asks here about the headers and footers (as the title of the question and one of the tags suggest)... At least, I answered having that in mind.

Comment: @Gonzalo. Perhaps.  I though Filokalos was asking about how to format the section headings (despite the choice of tags).  Perhaps you can clarify, Filokalos?

Comment: @Alan Munn Yes, you right, it's duplicated. Sorry. How could I delete this my topic?

Comment: If you want to delete it, there is a is a delete link at the bottom of the question.  Or you can leave it and it will be closed (which will stop more answers from being added.)

Comment: @Alan @filokalos: Since it was in fact a duplicate, I will delete my answer. Ah, I can't delete it since it was accepted!

Answer (score 2):

You can use either the [fancyhdr](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr) or the [titlesec](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) (with the `pagestyles` option) package to customize the headers and footers of a document.