# How do I install two fonts into a document?

Tags: fonts, installing

I want to install two fonts `tgchorus` and `fouriernc` into a document. The font `tgchorus` for content of chapters, section, subsection and `fouriernc` for remain. I don't know to install. How must I do?

Comment: You don't really "install" fonts into a document.  You just need to use font selection commands when you define your sectioning commands.  See [How do I use a particular font for a small section of my document](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25249/2693) on font selection commands. For changing fonts in section headings etc. see [How to set the font for \section title (and chapter etc.)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1455/2693).

Comment: While the question is interesting by itself, I recommend you *not* to use Zapf Chancery or any clone thereof for *any* purpose other than typesetting an invitation or something similar.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try the following.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}
%%
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
    {\fontfamily{qzc}\selectfont\Huge}
    {\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter:}{0pt}{\huge}
%
\usepackage{fouriernc}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\chapter{These Real Numbers}
\lipsum[1-2]

\end{document}
```

`\fontfamily{qzc}\selectfont` chooses "TeX Gyre Chorus" without loading `\usepackage{tgchorus}`.

[image]

But you'll get all sorts of values about the size of the font being requested.  I'm not sure you can overcome that.

Comment: I don't understand,  before I could do, but now, I can not do. I receive the massage not find font qzt.

Comment: How can I make font bigger and bold font for section in this line?
`\titleformat{\section}{\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{qzc}\normalfont\Large}{\thesection}{1em}{}
`