# How do I select font for an environment?

Tags: fonts, theorems, amsthm

I use `\usepackage{fouriernc}`. Now,  I want to select the font `chancery` for theorem environment. How can I choose the font for an environment, for example, theorem environment?

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}
\usepackage{fouriernc}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\chapter{These Real Numbers}
\lipsum[1-2]
\begin{theorem}
\fontfamily{qzc}\selectfont\large
This is a theorem Pythagore
$$a^2 + b^2 = c^2.$$
\end{theorem}
\end{document}
```

How can I input `\fontfamily{qzc}\selectfont\large` at  `\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}` before  `\begin{document}`?

Comment: Related question: [How do I install two fonts into a document?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88369/how-do-i-install-two-fonts-into-a-document).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can choose the font Chancery by:

```
\fontfamily{qzc}\selectfont
```

including it into a `\begingroup` ... `\endgroup` sequence holds the change local

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}
\usepackage{fouriernc}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newtheoremstyle{Special}%
  {3pt}%      ⟨Space above⟩
  {3pt}%      ⟨Space below⟩
  {\large\fontfamily{qzc}\selectfont}%⟨Body font⟩
  {}%         ⟨Indent amount⟩1
  {\itshape\bfseries}% ⟨Theorem head font⟩
  {:}%        ⟨Punctuation after theorem head⟩
  {.5em}%     ⟨Space after theorem head⟩2
  {}%         ⟨Theorem head spec (can be left empty, meaning ‘normal’)⟩
\theoremstyle{Special}
\newtheorem{Theorem}{Special}

\begin{document}
\chapter{These Real Numbers}
\lipsum[1-2]
\begin{Theorem}
This is a theorem Pythagore
$$a^2 + b^2 = c^2.$$
\end{Theorem}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried
\begin{theorem}
\fontfamily{qzc}\selectfont\Large
This is a theorem This is a theorem This is a theorem  This is a theorem  This is a theorem
\end{theorem}. How to input fontfamily{qzc}\selectfont\Large at premable \newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}?

Comment: create a _complete_ example! How should I know, what other packages do you load?

Comment: How do I get font size in body Theorem equal to font size outside `\begin{Theorem} \end{Theorem}`?  For example 12 pt at body Theorem.

Comment: if you have 11pt for the document wide font size then use `\large` for 12pt

Comment: I did so. But then font math in Theorem is bigger than  document wide font size.