# How to get a bigger font?

Tags: fontsize

At here [How do I install two fonts into a document?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88369/how-do-i-install-two-fonts-into-a-document) I used two fonts. How to get a bigger font for chapters, sections and subsections?

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}
%%
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
    {\fontfamily{qzc}\fontsize{120}{120}\selectfont}
    {\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter:}{0pt}{\huge}
%
\usepackage{fouriernc}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\chapter{These Real Numbers}
\lipsum[1-2]

\end{document}
```

[image]