# heading of section with first letter big capital letter and rest as small capital letters

Tags: formatting

How do i format the heading of the section such that first letter is bigger size capital letter and following letters as smaller sized capital letters in the same word ?

Comment: `\section{\textsc{Section Title}}`

Comment: to change it in the general see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1455/how-to-set-the-font-for-a-section-title-and-chapter-etc

Comment: How big a difference would you like between the first letter and the rest?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).

Comment: I marked it as a duplicate. If the answers to the other question would not help, or your question is really different, let us know by a comment. Feel free to edit your question.

Comment: The question in the link is a more generic question on formatting chapter headings or sections , mine is specific question on big and small capital letters in the same word of the title , please dont duplicate it

Comment: It's better to have a general question with general answers, so many users can be helped. Try the suggestions there (`titlesec` etc.) It's not a personal help forum ("how can I make the third letter in a word yellow in subsections in mythesis.cls") but a know-how site ("how can I change colors in headings"). Please follow the links in the answer of the other question, read the package manual there, which has the solution. Note, `\textsc` or `\scshape` is the font shape you need. You may look at the [tag:small-caps] tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `titlesec` for this, but need a helper command for the sizing, and need to place this command at the end of the "before code" section of `\titleformat`.

[image: Sample output]

```
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{textcase,relsize}

\def\myFBRSC#1{{\larger[3]{\MakeTextUppercase{#1}}}\scshape }
\DeclareRobustCommand{\FirstBigRestSmallCaps}[1]{\myFBRSC #1}

\titleformat{\section}%
{\normalfont\Large}{\thesection}{1em}{\FirstBigRestSmallCaps}

\begin{document}

\section{Test Section}

Some text.

\section{lower case section}

\end{document}
```

I have used `relsize` to do the size changing, with the addition of `fix-cm` to make larger fonts available.  The command `\MakeTextUppercase` is from `textcase`, but LaTeX's ordinary `\MakeUppercase` may be good enough for your purposes.  For the above code to work, the section heading should not start with a non-text token, such as a math character.