# Unbold section and subsection heading

Tags: fonts, sectioning, titlesec

I am using this format for my section and subsection headings (it is centered and numbers have dots):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[center]{titlesec}

\titlelabel{\thetitle.\quad} %dots after title number
```

But I cannot unbold it by using most of the unbold commands because centering changes in most of them. Is there way to unbold the section and subsection headings with this format?

Comment: You should use the `\titleformat` command to set the format of the section heading.

Comment: See (possible duplicate): [How to set the font for a `\section` title (and chapter etc)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1455/5764)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not want to use the `\titleformat` command, load the package with

```
\usepackage[center,md]{titlesec}
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is with `sectsty` and the “traditional” way for adding a period.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{sectsty}

\usepackage{lipsum} % just for the example

% titles are medium weight and centered
\allsectionsfont{\mdseries\centering}

% we want a period after the section number
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@seccntformat}[1]{\csname the#1\endcsname.\quad}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section{A section}
\lipsum[2]
\subsection{A subsection}
\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

[image]