# How to properly set font for document

Tags: fonts

I have bought and installed the font family Frutiger according to https://www.tug.org/fonts/fontinstall.html TexLive on Windows.

Now I would like to set Frutiger as the font for headings (sections and subsections, maybe subsubsections too) and Computer Modern as the font for anything else (text, captions, table of contents, etc.)

How do I do this in LaTeX? My current document looks like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{frutiger}

\begin{document}
\section{Section}
Text \textbf{text}
\subsection{Subsection}
Text
\end{document}
```

`\usepackage{frutiger}` uses `frutiger.sty` with the following content (I found it on the Internet because I didn't have it while installing the font):

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{frutiger}
    [2005/08/08 v1.2 Style file for Linotype Frutiger]
\RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}
\RequirePackage{textcomp}
\DeclareOption{lining}{\renewcommand*{\rmdefault}{lfrx}}
\DeclareOption{oldstyle}{\renewcommand*{\rmdefault}{lfrj}}
\ExecuteOptions{oldstyle}
\ProcessOptions\relax
%%
%% End of file 'frutiger.sty'
```

If it has to be specified, I'd use "Frutiger 57 Condensed" for headings, found in this document: http://mirror.jmu.edu/pub/CTAN/fonts/psfonts/w-a-schmidt/pfr.txt

If there is a template to set headings and continuous text, how would I have to define right the opposite of my question: Headings in Computer Modern Sans and text in Frutiger with bold using "Frutiger 65 Bold" from the above url?

Comment: I don't have the Frutiger font. But on any way you can change the font of the section headers in a KOMA-Script class like `scrartcl` with `\setkomafont{sectioning}{…}`

Comment: What form is the font in? (Opentype? Truetype? Type1?) Which instructions did you follow to install? The link you gave includes pointers to several different approaches based on various scenarios.  Schmidt's packages on CTAN may provide what you need if the fonts you have are appropriately named, installed and so on. But we can't know that from what you've told us.

Comment: @cfr thank you for your response. To be honest, I don't remember the setup back in July. I recently switched to LuaTeX and all my problems are gone by just using these commands:
`\usepackage{fontspec}
    \defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
    \setsansfont[]{Frutiger Neue LT W1G}
    \setmainfont[
        BoldFont={Frutiger Neue LT W1G Bold}, 
        ItalicFont={Frutiger Neue LT W1G Italic},
        BoldItalicFont={Frutiger Neue LT W1G Bold Italic}]{Frutiger Neue LT W1G Light}`

Answer (score 3):

I found your question because I just had... the same question!

I am using LaTeX standard **Helvetica** (it's not 100% equal to the original one I guess) since I don't own Frutiger. 
But you can just look at the [`FontName.pdf`](https://www.tug.org/fontname/fontname.pdf) file for the abbreviation of Frutiger (Thanks [David Carlisle](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/1090/david-carlisle) for the light on this great file). It should be something like `ftr` or `ftb`.

To keep Computer Modern for the whole text you don't need to change anything, it's already the default. As you mention sans, then just add:

```
\renewcommand*{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
```

If you are using KOMA-script it's recommended to use the following:

```
\newcommand*\sectfont{\fontfamily{phv}\selectfont}
```

Refer to section 3.2 [KOMA-Script](http://www.ctex.org/documents/packages/nonstd/koma-script.pdf)

You can also use the [`titlesec`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) package, as the following:

```
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}
  {\fontfamily{phv}\selectfont\bfseries\LARGE\color{blue}}
  {\thechapter}{20pt}{}
\titleformat{\section}
  {\fontfamily{phv}\selectfont\color{blue}}
  {\thechapter}{10pt}{}
```

[image: Chapter and section in blue helvetica, text in serif computer modern]

To customize it like I did refer to section 3 [titlesec](http://linorg.usp.br/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/titlesec/titlesec.pdf). I adapted the code from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1455/how-to-set-the-font-for-a-section-title-and-chapter-etc).

If you giveup KOMA-script then it's possivle to use the [`sectsty`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/sectsty) package.

```
\usepackage{sectsty}
\allsectionsfont{\fontfamily{phv}\selectfont}
```

[image: Chapter and section in helvetica, text in serif computer modern]

If you want the otherway around just add:

```
\renewcommand*\rmdefault{phv}
```

And replace `phv` with `cmss` on any of the above codes.

[image: Chapter and section in Serif Computer Modern, text in helvetica]

Another site I relay for quick reference on simple latex things is [LaTeX Wikibook](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Fonts#Available_LaTeX_Fonts_.5B2.5D).

Hope this helps you, even been 3 months later.

Comment: The very first sentence of the OP's post says that the OP has bought the fonts.... The information you give is useful to somebody wanting to use a different standardly installed font, but it does not really address this question which concerns a non-standard possibly-installed-or-maybe-not-properly-installed font ;).

Comment: Ops... Thanks for that. Considering the installation is ok, one should be able to call it using the abbreviation in the fontname file. But it seems like it's not such an easy process.