# How to set font family of chapter labels

Tags: chapters, titlesec

[This question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1455/how-to-set-the-font-for-a-section-title-and-chapter-etc) provides a code to set chapter font using `titlesec`, but doesn't say how to change the font family of each part (label and title).

How to change the font family of the "Chapter first" in the following example (for example to Tahoma) using this code and make it center? please note only the chapter label (Chapter #)

something like

```
                 Chapter first
              The theory of this work
```

Comment: Please, add the code you have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this to change the font only for the label:

```
\usepackage{fmtcount}
\usepackage{tahoma}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\filcenter}{\fontfamily{tahoma}\selectfont\MakeUppercase\chaptername~\ordinalstring{chapter}}{6ex}{}
```

Comment: I tried to use `XB Zar` instead of tahoma, as it is a Persian font, and receive this error `Package titlesec Error: Entered in horizontal mode. \tableofcontents`

Comment: Is there a LaTeX package to use it?  If not, you'll have to compile with `XeLaTeX` or `LuaLaTeX` and load fontspec.

Comment: I found a solution posted in  my answer, I needed the different font only for `Chapter #`

Comment: It should be simpler with `titlesec`. What's not clear to me, do you want to use this font  only for the label, not for the title?

Comment: Yes only for the label not title!

Answer (score 0):

The following code for Persian font `XB Zar` compiled by `Xelatex` do the tricks

```
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{xepersian}
\settextfont{XB Yagut}

%%  Change font of chapter titles and make it center

\defpersianfont\chapterfont[Scale=0.95]{XB Zar}

\makeatletter
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
   \vspace*{40\p@}%
    {\parindent \z@ \RTL\normalfont
        \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
        \if@mainmatter
        \Huge\filcenter\bfseries {\chapterfont \@chapapp}\space \thechapter
        \par\nobreak
        \vskip 15\p@
        \fi
        \fi
        \interlinepenalty\@M
        \huge \bfseries{\normalfont #1}\par\nobreak
        \vskip 30\p@
    }}
    \def\@makeschapterhead#1{%
        \vspace*{50\p@}%
        {\parindent \z@ \centering
            \normalfont
            \interlinepenalty\@M
            \Huge \bfseries   #1\par\nobreak
            \vskip 40\p@
        }}
        \makeatother
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


%%%% Make Chapter number ordinal (for Persian)
\makeatletter
\bidi@patchcmd{\@makechapterhead}{\thechapter}{\tartibi{chapter}}{}{}
\bidi@patchcmd{\chaptermark}{\thechapter}{\tartibi{chapter}}{}{}
\makeatother
%%=========================
```