# Memoir Class - Chapterstyle question

Tags: memoir

For my thesis I am using the Memoir class
`\documentclass[12pt,extrafontsizes,twoside,openright]{memoir}`
 and `\chapterstyle{ell}`, which produces a nice chapterhead with some sans-serif font.

However, the lower divisions like `\section` and `\subsection` etc. use the text font - just enlarged -  which does not at all fit the font of the chapter headline.
I am using the text memmen.pdf for instructions, but I cannot find a `\sectionstyle` or similar, nor do I know what font the `chapterstyle{ell}` uses to make my own `\sectionstyle`.
Short: the question is: where can I find the code of the `ell` chapterstyle?
Any idea is welcome!
Angelika

Comment: Never mind, I found it! My answer is here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1455/how-to-set-the-font-for-a-section-title-and-chapter-etc

Comment: I have added an answer as I didn't find your referenced answer particularly helpful with respect to your question.

Answer (score 1):

`\chapterstyle{ell}`, as it says in the manual (`texdoc memoir` or `texdoc memman`) is a sanserif font. Which particular one used is dependent on the font family used in *your* document.

`memoir` does not have a `\sectionstyle`, instead it provides individual commands for changing the layouts of `\section`, etc., titles (see section 6.6 in the manual). For a section heading font matching the `ell` style try along the lines:

```
\setsecheadstyle{\Large\sffamily}
```

Here is an MWE

```
% memellprob.tex SE 538923

\documentclass{memoir}

% you could call for a different font family here

\chapterstyle{ell}
\setsecheadstyle{\Large\sffamily}

\begin{document}

\chapter{The first}

\section{First section}

\subsection{First subsection}

\end{document}
```

Note that I haven't changed the `\subsection` font. It's up to you how you want the various sectional heading to look.