# Changing font style for subsection headers

Tags: fonts

I'm trying to change the subsection font style to:

[image]

Which comes from [this](https://www.overleaf.com/articles/130-cheat-sheet/ntwtkmpxmgrp) template where I just changed the black color to blue. This is current code and I've tried to use [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1455/how-to-set-the-font-for-a-section-title-and-chapter-etc) solution as a reference without success:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[a4paper, landscape, margin=0in]{geometry}
\usepackage{multicol,lipsum}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{.4pt}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\subsection}
  {\color{blue}\filleft{blue}}
  {\thesection}{1em}{}
 
\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{3}
% My code
% My code
% My code
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

I don't mind the blue horizontal line from the image, but it would be nice to have it as a separator, like:

> --0.0 Probability---------------

Where the length would be enough to cover the column itself (each page of the document has three columns)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution is obtained using the `sectsty` package.

[image: a]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[a4paper, landscape, margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{multicol,lipsum}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{.4pt}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{sectsty} % added <<<<<<<<<<<<
\subsectionfont{\rule[0.5ex]{30pt}{0.2pt}\color{white}\noindent\colorbox{blue}}% added <<<<<<

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{multicols}{3}
        \subsection{Probability}
    \end{multicols}
\end{document}
```